# What's the difference between faking, mocking, and stubbing?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, language-agnostic, terminology, definition

I know how I use these terms, but I'm wondering if there are accepted definitions for **faking**, **mocking**, and **stubbing** for unit tests?  How do you define these for your tests?  Describe situations where you might use each.

Here is how I use them:

**Fake**: a class that implements an interface but contains fixed data and no logic.  Simply returns "good" or "bad" data depending on the implementation.

**Mock**: a class that implements an interface and allows the ability to dynamically set the values to return/exceptions to throw from particular methods and provides the ability to check if particular methods have been called/not called.

**Stub**: Like a mock class, except that it doesn't provide the ability to verify that methods have been called/not called.

Generation of each:

- **Mocks** and **Stubs** can be hand-generated or generated by a mocking framework.
- **Fake classes** are generated by hand.

Using them as follows:

- **Mocks** primarily to verify interactions between my class and dependent classes.
- **Stubs** once I have verified the interactions and am testing alternate paths through my code.
- **Fake classes** primarily to abstract out data dependencies or when mocks/stubs are too tedious to set up each time.

Comment: Well you basically said it all in your "question" :)
I think those are pretty well accepted definitions of those terms

Comment: The Wikipedia definition of Fake differs from this, asserting that a Fake "is used as a simpler implementation, e.g. using an in-memory database in the tests instead of doing real database access)"  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_double

Comment: I learned a lot from the following resource, with an excellent explanation by Robert C. Martin (Uncle Bob): [The Little Mocker on The Clean Code Blog](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/14/TheLittleMocker.html).

It explains the differences between and subtleties of dummies, test doubles, stubs, spies, (true) mocks and fakes.

It also mentions Martin Fowler and it explains a bit of software testing history.

Comment: https://testing.googleblog.com/2013/07/testing-on-toilet-know-your-test-doubles.html (a short one-page summary).

Comment: Here is my take to explain that: [Test Doubles: Fakes, Stubs and Mocks](https://blog.pragmatists.com/test-doubles-fakes-mocks-and-stubs-1a7491dfa3da) (blog post with examples)

Comment: There is not any "accepted definition" for "mocking, and stubbing for unit tests" - because there is none for "unit" itself.

Answer (score 708, accepted):

You can get some information :

### From [Martin Fowler about Mock and Stub](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html)

**Fake** objects actually have working implementations, but usually take some shortcut which makes them not suitable for production

**Stubs** provide canned answers to calls made during the test, usually not responding at all to anything outside what's programmed in for the test. Stubs may also record information about calls, such as an email gateway stub that remembers the messages it 'sent', or maybe only how many messages it 'sent'.

**Mocks** are what we are talking about here: objects pre-programmed with expectations which form a specification of the calls they are expected to receive.

### From [xunitpattern](http://xunitpatterns.com):

**Fake**: We acquire or build a very lightweight implementation of the same functionality as provided by a component that the SUT depends on and instruct the SUT to use it instead of the real.

**Stub** : This implementation is configured to respond to calls from the SUT with the values (or exceptions) that will exercise the Untested Code (see Production Bugs on page X) within the SUT. A key indication for using a Test Stub is having Untested Code caused by the inability to control the indirect inputs of the SUT

**Mock Object** that implements the same interface as an object on which the SUT (System Under Test) depends. We can use a Mock Object as an observation point when we need to do Behavior Verification to avoid having an Untested Requirement (see Production Bugs on page X) caused by an inability to observe side-effects of invoking methods on the SUT.

### Personally

I try to simplify by using : Mock and Stub. I use Mock when it's an object that returns a value that is set to the tested class. I use Stub to mimic an Interface or Abstract class to be tested. In fact, it doesn't really matter what you call it, they are all classes that aren't used in production, and are used as utility classes for testing.

Comment: It seems to me the definitions for Stub and Fake are reversed in the xUnitPattern quote compared to Martin Fowler's quote.  Also, that Martin Fowler's definitions of Stub and Fake are reversed compared to the definitions in tvanfosson's original question.  In reality is there any generally accepted definitions of those two terms or does it just depend on who you're talking to?

Comment: +1 for "I try to simplify by using : Mock and Stub". That's a great idea!

Comment: Can't see how using only Mock and Stub is a great idea. Every test double has its purposes and, thus, its uses.

Comment: I can't  see the difference between Fake and Mock in MF's definition.

Comment: @MusuNaji: In MF's definition there are no "expectations" in regarding the conversation for a Fake, other than it has an implementation for it's interface. On the other hand the Mock will be challenged (was this method called?).

Comment: Personally, i don't encourage the use of Mocks. I've see far too many tests that don't test anything. Mocks allow bad smells in the code, by allowing the tests to circumvent problems, instead of having the developer fix the issue. Not they are not useful, but more often than not, i see them associated with poor tests.

Comment: @Brill Pappin how do you approach integration tests or e2e without Mocks?

Comment: @Luke we're talking Unit tests here, which are different. An integration test should have real system behind it. However, if you can use a Mock in your integration test, then you can use a fake or a stub (depending on your definition). if you have to use a Mock, then you are *probably* testing the mock, and not the integration. However, one place Mocks really do come in handy, is when you have a poorly written api that you can't easily test. In those cases, Mocks can be a lifesaver. IMO of course.

Answer (score 308):

**Stub** - an object that provides predefined answers to method calls.

**Mock** - an object on which you set expectations.

**Fake** - an object with limited capabilities (for the purposes of testing), e.g. a fake web service.

Test Double is the general term for stubs, mocks and fakes. But informally, you'll often hear people simply call them mocks.

Comment: Could anybody explain & define to me what is a "canned answer" in this context?

Comment: An explicit value, rather than a value that is calculated.

Comment: Finally! Some definitions I can understand! Based on these definitions, then, [googletest (gtest) / googlemock (gmock)](https://github.com/google/googletest) allows mocked objects to also be stubs, as you can create `EXPECT_CALL()`s on a mocked method which force certain outputs based on certain inputs, by using the `.WillOnce(Invoke(my_func_or_lambda_func))` (or with `.WillRepeatedly()`) type syntax attached to an `EXPECT_CALL()`. Some examples of using `Invoke()` can be seen in a different context at the bottom of my long answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60905880/4561887.

Comment: Gmock documentation on `Invoke()` is here: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cheat_sheet.md#using-a-function-functor-or-lambda-as-an-action. Anyway, the conclusion is: **Google mock (gmock) allows one to easily create both mocks _and_ stubs**, though most mocks are not stubs.

Comment: Mocks are a superset of Stubs, they can still return predefined answers but also allow the developer to set expectations. IMO certain libraries out there blur the lines of all of the testing dummies.

Comment: I don't like this terminology. This "setting an expectation on mocks" is either a wrong abstraction or too specialised. You could just straight-forwardly create a mock object, exercise some function on it and compare the result to some well-known result. "Setting an expectation" is never explicitly done that way. In fact, in many frameworks, the expectation is not seen as part of the mock

Comment: @IceFire - perhaps a clearer way of saying it would be "an object on which you verify interactions". My wording/experience was from using https://site.mockito.org/ (10 years ago)

Answer (score 130):

I am surprised that this question has been around for so long and nobody has as yet provided an answer based on [Roy Osherove's "The Art of Unit Testing"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617290890).

In "3.1 Introducing stubs" defines a stub as:

> A stub is a controllable replacement for an existing dependency
>   (or collaborator) in the system. By using a stub, you can test your code without
>   dealing with the dependency directly.

And defines the difference between stubs and mocks as:

> The main thing to remember about mocks versus stubs is that mocks are just like stubs, but you assert against the mock object, whereas you do not assert against a stub.

Fake is just the name used for both stubs and mocks. For example when you don't care about the distinction between stubs and mocks.

The way Osherove's distinguishes between stubs and mocks, means that any class used as a fake for testing can be both a stub or a mock. Which it is for a specific test depends entirely on how you write the checks in your test.

- When your test checks values in the class under test, or actually anywhere but the fake, the fake was used as a stub. It just provided values for the class under test to use, either directly through values returned by calls on it or indirectly through causing side effects (in some state) as a result of calls on it.
- When your test checks values of the fake, it was used as a mock.

Example of a test where class FakeX is used as a stub:

```
const pleaseReturn5 = 5;
var fake = new FakeX(pleaseReturn5);
var cut = new ClassUnderTest(fake);

cut.SquareIt;

Assert.AreEqual(25, cut.SomeProperty);
```

The `fake` instance is used as a stub because the `Assert` doesn't use `fake` at all.

Example of a test where test class X is used as a mock:

```
const pleaseReturn5 = 5;
var fake = new FakeX(pleaseReturn5);
var cut = new ClassUnderTest(fake);

cut.SquareIt;

Assert.AreEqual(25, fake.SomeProperty);
```

In this case the `Assert` checks a value on `fake`, making that fake a mock.

Now, of course these examples are highly contrived, but I see great merit in this distinction. It makes you aware of how you are testing your stuff and where the dependencies of your test are.

I agree with Osherove's that

> from a pure maintainability perspective, in my tests using mocks creates more trouble than not using them. That has been my experience, but I’m always learning something new.

Asserting against the fake is something you really want to avoid as it makes your tests highly dependent upon the implementation of a class that isn't the one under test at all. Which means that the tests for class `ActualClassUnderTest` can start breaking because the implementation for `ClassUsedAsMock` changed. And that sends up a foul smell to me. Tests for `ActualClassUnderTest` should preferably only break when `ActualClassUnderTest` is changed.

I realize that writing asserts against the fake is a common practice, especially when you are a mockist type of TDD subscriber. I guess I am firmly with Martin Fowler in the classicist camp (See [Martin Fowler's "Mocks aren't Stubs"](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html)) and like Osherove avoid interaction testing (which can only be done by asserting against the fake) as much as possible.

For fun reading on why you should avoid mocks as defined here, google for "fowler mockist classicist". You'll find a plethora of opinions.

Answer (score 117):

As mentioned by the top-voted answer, Martin Fowler discusses these distinctions in [Mocks Aren't Stubs](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html), and in particular the subheading [The Difference Between Mocks and Stubs](https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#TheDifferenceBetweenMocksAndStubs), so make sure to read that article.

Rather than focusing on *how* these things are different, I think it's more enlightening to focus on *why* these are distinct concepts. Each exists for a different purpose.

### Fakes

A **fake** is an implementation that behaves "naturally", but is not "real". These are fuzzy concepts and so different people have different understandings of what makes things a fake.

One example of a fake is an in-memory database (e.g. using sqlite with the `:memory:` store). You would never use this for production (since the data is not persisted), but it's perfectly adequate as a database to use in a testing environment. It's also much more lightweight than a "real" database.

As another example, perhaps you use some kind of object store (e.g. Amazon S3) in production, but in a test you can simply save objects to files on disk; then your "save to disk" implementation would be a fake. (Or you could even fake the "save to disk" operation by using an in-memory filesystem instead.)

As a third example, imagine an object that provides a cache API; an object that implements the correct interface but that simply performs no caching at all but always returns a cache miss would be a kind of fake.

**The purpose of a fake is *not* to affect the behavior of the system under test**, but rather to *simplify the implementation* of the test (by removing unnecessary or heavyweight dependencies).

### Stubs

A **stub** is an implementation that behaves "unnaturally". It is preconfigured (usually by the test set-up) to respond to specific inputs with specific outputs.

**The purpose of a stub is to get your system under test into a specific state.** For example, if you are writing a test for some code that interacts with a REST API, you could *stub out* the REST API with an API that always returns a canned response, or that responds to an API request with a specific error. This way you could write tests that make assertions about how the system reacts to these states; for example, testing the response your users get if the API returns a 404 error.

A stub is usually implemented to only respond to the exact interactions you've told it to respond to. But the key feature that makes something a stub is its *purpose*: a stub is all about setting up your test case.

### Mocks

A **mock** is similar to a stub, but with *verification* added in. **The purpose of a mock is to make assertions about how your system under test interacted with the dependency**.

For example, if you are writing a test for a system that uploads files to a website, you could build a *mock* that accepts a file and that you can use to assert that the uploaded file was correct. Or, on a smaller scale, it's common to use a mock of an object to verify that the system under test calls specific methods of the mocked object.

Mocks are tied to *interaction testing*, which is a specific testing methodology. People who prefer to test *system state* rather than *system interactions* will use mocks sparingly if at all.

### Test doubles

Fakes, stubs, and mocks all belong to the category of *test doubles*. A test double is any object or system you use in a test *instead of* something else. Most automated software testing involves the use of test doubles of some kind or another. Some other kinds of test doubles include **dummy values**, **spies**, and I/O **blackholes**.

Comment: I've read all the answers. I think this is the best clarification so far.

Comment: Reading this yet again several years later and still one of the best answers.

Comment: What is _interaction_ testing, as in _`Mocks are tied to interaction testing [...]`_? Is it different from _integration_ testing?

Comment: As well as Test doubles being a term that encapsulates Fakes, Mocks and Stubs, the term Fake in itself can sometimes be considered a general term that includes Mocks and Stubs.

Answer (score 33):

The thing that you assert on it is called a **mock** object.

Everything else that just helped the test run is a **stub**.

Comment: while other answers have great detail and are really good. this one makes it so clear  and easy to make the difference, it's hard to not upvote. gj!

Answer (score 21):

All of them are called Test Doubles and used to inject the dependencies that your test case needs.

[image: Fake]

Stub:
It already has a predefined behavior to set your expectation
for example, stub returns only the success case of your API response
[image: Stub]

A mock is a smarter stub. You verify your test passes through it.
so you could make amock that return either the success or failure success depending on the condition could be changed in your test case.
[image: Mock]

[image: Dummy]

[image: Spy]

Comment: Interesting to see these in Swift, vs the JavaScript/Jest tools that I'm currently using.

Answer (score 17):

**Test doubles types**

`Unit testing` - is an approach of testing where the unit(class, method) is under control.

`Test double` - is not a primary object(from OOP world). It is a realisation which is created **temporary** to test, check or during development. And they are created for **closing dependencies**  of tested unit(method, class...)

Test doubles types:

- `fake object` is a real **implementation** of interface(protocol) or an **extend** which is using an inheritance or other approaches which can be used to create - **`is`** dependency. Usually it is created by developer as a simplest solution to substitute some dependency
- `stub object` is a bare object(0, nil and methods without logic) with **extra state** which is predefined(by developer) to define **returned values**. Usually it is created by framework

```
class StubA: A {
    override func foo() -> String {
        return "My Stub"
    }
}
```

- `mock object` is very similar to `stub object` but the **extra state** is changed during program execution to check if **something happened**(method was called, arguments, when, how often...).

```
class MockA: A {
    var isFooCalled = false
    override func foo() -> String {
        isFooCalled = true
        return "My Mock"
    }
}
```

- `spy object` is a real object with a "partial mocking". It means that you work with a **non-double** object except mocked behavior
- `dummy object` is object which is necessary to run a test but no one variable or method of this object is not called.

**stub vs mock**

[Martin Fowler said](https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html)

> There is a difference in that the stub uses state verification while the mock uses behavior verification.

[[Mockito mock vs spy]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62555181/4770877)

Answer (score 16):

To illustrate the usage of stubs and mocks, I would like to also include an example based on Roy Osherove’s [*The Art of Unit Testing*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1617290890).

Imagine, we have a LogAnalyzer application which has the sole functionality of printing logs. It not only needs to talk to a web service, but if the web service throws an error, LogAnalyzer has to log the error to a different external dependency, sending it by email to the web service administrator.

Here is the logic we would like to test inside LogAnalyzer:

```
if (fileName.Length < 8) {
  try {
    webService.LogError("Filename too short: " + fileName);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    emailService.SendEmail("to", "subject", e.Message);
  }
}
```

How do you test that LogAnalyzer calls the email service correctly when the web service throws an exception? Here are the questions we are faced with:

- How can we replace the web service?
- How can we simulate an exception from the web service so that we can test the call to the email service?
- How will we know that the email service was called correctly or at all?

To deal with the first two questions, we can **use a stub for the web service**. To solve the third problem, we can **use a mock for the email service**.

A fake is a generic term that can be used to describe either a stub or a mock. In our test, we will have two fakes. One will be the email service mock, which we will use to verify that the correct parameters were sent to the email service. The other will be a stub that we will use to simulate an exception thrown from the web service. The web service is a stub because we won’t be using it to verify the test result, only to make sure the test runs correctly. The email service is a mock because we will assert against it that it was called correctly.

```
[TestFixture]
public class LogAnalyzer2Tests {
  [Test]
  public void Analyze_WebServiceThrows_SendsEmail() {
    StubWebService stubWebService = new StubWebService();
    stubWebService.ToThrow = new Exception("fake exception");
    MockEmailService mockEmailService = new MockEmailService();

    LogAnalyzer2 log = new LogAnalyzer2();
    log.Service = stubWebService
    log.Email = mockEmailService;
    string tooShortFileName = "abc.ext";
    log.Analyze(tooShortFileName);

    Assert.AreEqual(mockEmailService.To, "to"); // mock used
    Assert.AreEqual(mockEmailService.Subject, "subject"); // mock used
    Assert.AreEqual(mockEmailService.Body, "fake exception"); // mock used
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

If you are familiar with Arrange-Act-Assert, then one way of explaining the difference between stub and mock that might be useful for you, is that stubs belong to the arrange section as they are for arranging input state, and mocks belong to the assert section as they are for asserting results against.

Dummies don't do anything. They are just for filling up parameter lists, so that you don't get undefined or null errors. They also exist to satisfy the type checker in statically typed languages, so that you can be allowed to compile and run.

Answer (score 8):

Stub, Fakes and Mocks have different meanings across different sources. I suggest you to introduce your team internal terms and agree upon their meaning.

I think it is important to distinguish between two approaches:
 - behaviour validation (implies behaviour substitution)
 - end-state validation (implies behaviour emulation)

Consider email sending in case of error. When doing behaviour validation - you check that method `Send` of `IEmailSender` was executed once. And you need to emulate return result of this method, return Id of the sent message. So you say: *"I expect that `Send` will be called. And I will just return dummy (or random) Id for any call"*. This is behaviour validation:
`emailSender.Expect(es=>es.Send(anyThing)).Return((subject,body) => "dummyId")`

When doing state validation you will need to create `TestEmailSender` that implements `IEmailSender`. And implement `Send` method - by saving input to some data structure that will be used for future state verification like array of some objects `SentEmails` and then it tests you will check that `SentEmails` contains expected email. This is state validation:
`Assert.AreEqual(1, emailSender.SentEmails.Count)`

From my readings I understood that **Behaviour validation** usually called **Mocks**.
And **State validation** usually called **Stubs** or **Fakes**.

Comment: Really well detailed and crisp defintion.

Answer (score 6):

It's a matter of making the tests expressive. I set expectations on a Mock if I want the test to describe a relationship between two objects. I stub return values if I'm setting up a supporting object to get me to the interesting behaviour in the test.

Answer (score 3):

**stub** and **fake** are objects in that they can vary their response based on input parameters. the main difference between them is that a Fake is closer to a real-world implementation than a stub. Stubs contain basically hard-coded responses to an expected request. Let see an example:

```
public class MyUnitTest {

 @Test
 public void testConcatenate() {
  StubDependency stubDependency = new StubDependency();
  int result = stubDependency.toNumber("one", "two");
  assertEquals("onetwo", result);
 }
}

public class StubDependency() {
 public int toNumber(string param) {
  if (param == “one”) {
   return 1;
  }
  if (param == “two”) {
   return 2;
  }
 }
}
```

A **mock** is a step up from fakes and stubs. Mocks provide the same functionality as stubs but are more complex. They can have rules defined for them that dictate in what order methods on their API must be called. Most mocks can track how many times a method was called and can react based on that information. Mocks generally know the context of each call and can react differently in different situations. Because of this, mocks require some knowledge of the class they are mocking. a stub generally cannot track how many times a method was called or in what order a sequence of methods was called. A mock looks like:

```
public class MockADependency {

 private int ShouldCallTwice;
 private boolean ShouldCallAtEnd;
 private boolean ShouldCallFirst;

 public int StringToInteger(String s) {
  if (s == "abc") {
   return 1;
  }
  if (s == "xyz") {
   return 2;
  }
  return 0;
 }

 public void ShouldCallFirst() {
  if ((ShouldCallTwice > 0) || ShouldCallAtEnd)
   throw new AssertionException("ShouldCallFirst not first thod called");
  ShouldCallFirst = true;
 }

 public int ShouldCallTwice(string s) {
  if (!ShouldCallFirst)
   throw new AssertionException("ShouldCallTwice called before ShouldCallFirst");
  if (ShouldCallAtEnd)
   throw new AssertionException("ShouldCallTwice called after ShouldCallAtEnd");
  if (ShouldCallTwice >= 2)
   throw new AssertionException("ShouldCallTwice called more than twice");
  ShouldCallTwice++;
  return StringToInteger(s);
 }

 public void ShouldCallAtEnd() {
  if (!ShouldCallFirst)
   throw new AssertionException("ShouldCallAtEnd called before ShouldCallFirst");
  if (ShouldCallTwice != 2) throw new AssertionException("ShouldCallTwice not called twice");
  ShouldCallAtEnd = true;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the book "Unit Testing Principles, Practices, and Patterns by Vladimir Khorikov" :

- **Mocks:** help to emulate and examine *outcoming interactions*. These interactions are calls the SUT makes to its dependencies to change their state. In other words it helps to examine the interaction (behaviour) of SUT and its dependencies. mocks could be :

  1. Spy : created manually
  2. Mocks : created using framework
- **Stubs:** helps to emulate *incoming interactions*. These interactions are calls the SUT makes to its dependencies to get input data. IN other words it helps to test the data passed to SUT. It could be 3 types

  1. Fake: is usually implemented to replace a dependency that doesn’t yet exist.
  2. Dummy: is hard-coded value.
  3. Stubs: Fledged dependency that you configure to return different values for different scenarios.

Comment: If anyone is wondering what SUT is, it's "System Under Test".

Answer (score 2):

In [xUnit Test Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131495054) book by Gerard Meszaros There is a nice table that gives a good insight about differences

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**From [Practical Unit Testing with JUnit and Mockito](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8395185146) by Tomek Kaczanowski**

**Dummies** and **stubs** are used to **prepare the environment** for testing. They are not used for verification. A dummy is employed to be passed as a value (e.g. as a parameter of a direct method call), while a stub passes some data to the SUT, substituting for one of its DOCs.

The purpose of **test spies** and **mocks** is to **verify the correctness of the communication between the SUT and DOCs**.

**Fake** works almost as good as the real collaborator, but is somehow simpler and/or weaker (which makes it not suitable for production use). It is also usually "cheaper" in use (i.e. faster or simpler to set up), which makes it suited to tests (which should run as fast as possible). A typical example is
an in-memory database that is used instead of a full-blown database server. It can be used for some tests, as it serves SQL requests pretty well; however, you would not want to use it in a production environment. In tests, fake plays a similar role to **dummy and stub**: it is a part of the environment (test fixture), not an object of verification. Fakes are used in **integration tests** rather than in unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use just 2 terms - **Fake** and **Mock**.

**Mock** only when using a mocking framework like *Moq* for example because it doesn't seem right to refer to it as a *Fake* when it's being created with `new Mock<ISomething>()` - while you can technically use a mocking framework to create *Stubs* or *Fakes*, it just seems kind of dumb to call it that in this situation - it has to be a *Mock*.

**Fake** for everything else. If a *Fake* can be summarised as *an implementation with reduced capabilities*, then I think a *Stub* could also be a *Fake* (and if not, who cares, everyone knows what I mean, and not once has anyone ever said *"I think you'll find that's a Stub"*)