# assert property of mocked object has been assigned correctly using Rhino.Mocks

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, rhino-mocks, mvp, linq-to-nhibernate

In a (web) application I've implemented the MVP pattern for seperation of core concerns. My presenters directly query the database using LINQ-to-NHibernate, or sometimes they use query objects when the query becomes complex (but I digress).

An simple example of one of my presenters is as follows (note: VB.NET is not my preference, but a requirement for this):

```
Public Class CampusListPresenter
    Inherits BasePresenter(Of ICampusListView)

    Public Sub New(ByVal view As ICampusListView)
        MyBase.New(view)
    End Sub

    Public Sub NeedDataSource()

        Using uow As ISession = _sessionManager.OpenSession()

            _view.DataSource = uow.Queryable(Of Campus)() _
            .Cacheable() _
            .AsEnumerable()

        End Using

    End Sub

End Class
```

The (simplified) base presenter class is as follows:

```
Public MustInherit Class BasePresenter(Of TView)

    Protected _view As TView

    Protected _sessionManager As ISessionManager

    Public Sub New(ByVal view As TView)
        Guard.Against(view Is Nothing, "view cannot be null.")
        _view = view
    End Sub

    Public WriteOnly Property SessionManager As ISessionManager
        Set(ByVal value As ISessionManager)
            _sessionManager = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

I'm trying to unit test my presenters (specifically the LINQ queries) using NUnit and Rhino Mocks. In my unit test case for the above CampusListPresenter, I pass a mocked view to the presenter. Essentially I want perform an assertion on this mocked view object to confirm the Datasouce property gets set appropriately. However, this is always null.

A (simplified) example of my unit test is as follows (understand I'm relatively new to proper unit testing):

```
<TestFixture()> _
Public Class CampusListPresenterTests

    Dim _realSessionManager As ISessionManager

    <TestFixtureSetUp()> _
    Public Sub TestFixtureSetUp()
        _realSessionManager = DefaultSessionManager.Instance
    End Sub

    Dim _view As ICampusListView
    Dim _fakeSessionManager As ISessionManager

    <SetUp()> _
    Public Sub Setup()
        _view = MockRepository.GenerateMock(Of ICampusListView)()
        _fakeSessionManager = MockRepository.GenerateMock(Of ISessionManager)()
    End Sub

    <Test()> _
    Public Sub NeedDataSource_UsingRealSession_DataSourceIsAssigned()

        'Arrange
        Dim realSession As ISession = _realSessionManager.OpenSession()
        _fakeSessionManager.Expect(Function(sm) sm.OpenSession()).Return(realSession)

        'Act
        Dim presenter As New CampusListPresenter(_view)
        presenter.SessionManager = _fakeSessionManager
        presenter.NeedDataSource()

        'Assert
        _fakeSessionManager.VerifyAllExpectations()
        Assert.AreEqual(_view.DataSource, realSession.Queryable(Of Campus)())

    End Sub

End Class
```

I actually setup my unit tests to use an in memory SQLite database and populate/destroy data in the setup/teardown methods, but this has all been omitted from the above example for simplicty.

Basically, in this unit test I'm returning a real NHibernate ISession from a mocked session manager (a class used for session management - think Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration) so that the LINQ-to-NHibernate can/will actually return valid enumerable results. Anyway in the presenter implementation I assign the views datasource (inside NeedDataSource), but when I do an assertion on this property the assigned value is always null.

Can anyone help me out?

Kind regards,
Ryan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mocked `ICampusListView` is unable to keep hold of the assigned datasource object. Here are two possible ways to fix this. First, you could use a stub instead of a mock (for more background info on the difference between mocks and stubs, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463707/what-are-the-differences-between-mocks-and-stubs-on-rhino-mocks) post):

```
_view = MockRepository.GenerateStub(Of ICampusListView)()
```

If you do want to use mocks instead of stubs, use `Expect` and `VerifyAllExpectations` on the `ICampusListView` object in your test:

```
    'Arrange
    Dim realSession As ISession = _realSessionManager.OpenSession()
    _fakeSessionManager.Expect(Function(sm) sm.OpenSession()).Return(realSession)
    _view.Expect(Function(v) v.SetDataSource(Arg(Of DataSource).Is.Anything))

    'Act
    Dim presenter As New CampusListPresenter(_view)
    presenter.SessionManager = _fakeSessionManager
    presenter.NeedDataSource()

    'Assert
    _fakeSessionManager.VerifyAllExpectations()
    _view.VerifyAllExpectations()
    Assert.AreEqual(_view.DataSource, realSession.Queryable(Of Campus)())
```