# RhinoMocks return value when a method has not been called

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I want to do the following...

Until a method has been called a certain property must always return value x
After a method has been called a certain property must always return value y

I am familiar with the WhenCalled method in RhinoMocks, which allows me to set that return value after the method has been called, but I cannot think of a way to set the return value before the call. So far I have the following code...

```
counter.Expect(n => n.IncreaseCounter())
   .WhenCalled(i => counter.Expect(n => n.GetCounter)
   .Return(Y).Repeat.Any());
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 solutions to do the trick:

1. With usage `WhenCalled()`:

   ```
   var counter = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ICounter>();

   int cnt = 1;

   counter
       .Stub(c => c.GetCounter)
       .Return(0)
       .WhenCalled(invocation => { invocation.ReturnValue = cnt; });

   counter
       .Stub(c => c.IncreaseCounter())
       .WhenCalled(invocation => { ++cnt; });
   ```
2. With usage `Do()` handler

   ```
   var counter = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ICounter>();

   int cnt = 1;

   counter
       .Stub(c => c.GetCounter)
       .Do((Func<int>)(() => cnt));

   counter
       .Stub(c => c.IncreaseCounter())
       .Do((Action)(() => ++cnt));
   ```

The idea is the same in both cases: Initially `GetCounter` returns `1`. Each `IncreaseConter()` call increases value which is returned by `GetCounter`.

PS
If you are not going to do assertions against `counter` then it is probably suitable to setup it with `Stub()` rather than with `Expect()`. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463707/what-are-the-differences-between-mocks-and-stubs-on-rhino-mocks) for details.

Comment: Thanks Alex, this helped and was jsut what I was looking for... with a slight modification

Answer (score 1):

Just setup new return value for property in a callback of mocked method:

```
Mock<IFoo> fooMock = new Mock<IFoo>();
fooMock.Setup(foo => foo.Property).Returns(1);
fooMock.Setup(foo => foo.Method())
       .Callback(() => fooMock.Setup(x => x.Property).Returns(42));
```

Mocked property will return `1` until mocked method will be called. Then its return value will be set to `42`. All further calls to mocked property will return `42`.

Comment: Oops, my bad :) Will fix soon

Answer (score 0):

Based on Alexander's solution... the following was what I was looking for...

```
var counter = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ICounter>();

int x = 1;
int y = 2;
int cnt = x;

counter
    .Stub(c => c.GetCounter)
    .Return(0)
    .WhenCalled(invocation =>
    {
        invocation.ReturnValue = cnt;
        cnt = y;
    });
```