# Why do Rhino Stubs allow me to set expectations on them?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

This question clarifies the conceptual differences between mocks and stubs in Rhino: [What are the differences between mocks and stubs on Rhino Mocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463707/what-are-the-differences-between-mocks-and-stubs-on-rhino-mocks)

However I'm left confused why Rhino Stub objects provide methods such as `.Expect` and `.VerifyAllExpectations()` when these appear to do nothing at all. Why do mock/stub objects seemingly provide the same interface?

It's making me think I've missed something fundamental - or is it just an implementation quirk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is based on IntelliSense limitation(on extension methods) + Rhinomocks design( + bug on the asserts) as I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37504346/4332059).

The following example shows that the `Expect` method has nothing more than `Stub` method on stubs.

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual string DoSomthing()
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {

        var f = MockRepository.GenerateStub<Foo>();

        f.Expect(x => x.DoSomthing())
         .Return("2");

        f.VerifyAllExpectations();

    }
}
```

If you'll execute the above example you'll see that the test won't fail(Although `DoSomthing` was never called...)