# Mocking a Spy method with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I am writing a unit test for a `FizzConfigurator` class that looks like:

```
public class FizzConfigurator {
    public void doFoo(String msg) {
        doWidget(msg, Config.ALWAYS);
    }

    public void doBar(String msg) {
        doWidget(msg, Config.NEVER);
    }

    public void doBuzz(String msg) {
        doWidget(msg, Config.SOMETIMES);
    }

    public void doWidget(String msg, Config cfg) {
        // Does a bunch of stuff and hits a database.
    }
}
```

I'd like to write a simple unit test that stubs the `doWidget(String,Config)` method (so that it doesn't actually fire and hit the database), but that allows me to *verify* that calling `doBuzz(String)` ends up executing `doWidget`. Mockito seems like the right tool for the job here.

```
public class FizzConfiguratorTest {
    @Test
    public void callingDoBuzzAlsoCallsDoWidget() {
        FizzConfigurator fixture = Mockito.spy(new FizzConfigurator());
        Mockito.when(fixture.doWidget(Mockito.anyString(), Config.ALWAYS)).
            thenThrow(new RuntimeException());

        try {
            fixture.doBuzz("This should throw.");

            // We should never get here. Calling doBuzz should invoke our
            // stubbed doWidget, which throws an exception.
            Assert.fail();
        } catch(RuntimeException rte) {
            return; // Test passed.
        }
    }
}
```

This *seems* like a good gameplan (to me at least). But when I actually go to code it up, I get the following compiler error on the 2nd line inside the test method (the `Mockito.when(...)` line:

> The method when(T) in the type Mockito is not applicable for the arguments (void)

I see that Mockito can't mock a method that returns `void`. So I ask:

1. Am I approaching this test setup correctly? Or is there a better, Mockito-recommended, way of testing that `doBuzz` calls `doWidget` under the hood? And
2. What can I do about mocking/stubbing `doWidget` as it is the most critical method of my entire `FizzConfigurator` class?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I wouldn't use exceptions to test that, but verifications. And another problem is that you can't use `when()` with methods returning void.

Here's how I would do it:

```
FizzConfigurator fixture = Mockito.spy(new FizzConfigurator());
doNothing().when(fixture).doWidget(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.<Config>any()));
fixture.doBuzz("some string");
Mockito.verify(fixture).doWidget("some string", Config.SOMETIMES);
```

Comment: Another problem is that `when()` can't be used on spies - take a look at the Mockito documentation on [using spies](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13) (note the gotcha) and [the do* methods](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12).

Comment: And check if a call do [``Mockito.reset``](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#17) has sneaked into your code - the mock forgets interactions & stubbing.

Comment: use only doReturn or doNothing, when mocking methods on spyFixture, otherwise you endup calling actual methods.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620103/mockito-trying-to-spy-on-method-is-calling-the-original-method

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a direct answer to the question, but I ran across it when trying to troubleshoot my problem and haven't since found a more relevant question.

If you're trying to stub/mock an object marked as Spy, Mockito only picks up the stubs if they're created using the `do...when` convention as hinted at by JB Nizet:

```java
doReturn(Set.of(...)).when(mySpy).getSomething(...);
```

It wasn't being picked up by:

```java
when(mySpy.getSomething(...)).thenReturn(Set.of(...));
```

Which matches the comment in `MockHandlerImpl::handle`:

```
// stubbing voids with doThrow() or doAnswer() style
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a clear sign that `doWidget` method should belong to another class which `FizzConfigurator` would depend on.

In your test, this new dependency would be a mock, and you could easily verify if its method was called with `verify`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, for the method I was trying to stub, I was passing in incorrect matchers.

My method signature (for the super class method I was trying to stub): String, Object.

I was passing in:

`myMethod("string", Mockito.nullable(ClassType.class))` and getting:

`Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed`

When using a matcher in another parameter, we also need to use one for the string:

`myMethod(eq("string"), Mockito.nullable(ClassType.class))`

Hope this helps!