# then return in Mockito run the code. with no reason

Tags: java, scala, mockito

In Scala, I noticed that when using when and thenReturn in Mockito, thenReturn runs the actual function before "replacing" the return value from the function.
for example -

```
class clsToTest() {
  def functionToTest: String = {
    if(condition-that-evaluated-to-true-sometimes) {
      throw new RuntimeException("some error")
    }
    "function-completed"
  }
}

testclsToTest() {
   test("test functionToTest") {
     val spiedclsToTest = spy(new clsToTest())
     when(spiedScalaSharedLibConfigManager.functionToTest).thenReturn("value to replace")
     //spiedScalaSharedLibConfigManager.otherFunctionThatUsesFunctionToTest()
  }
}
```

but when the line

```
when(spiedScalaSharedLibConfigManager.functionToTest).thenReturn("value to replace")
```

is executed, because sometimes `condition-that-evaluated-to-true-sometimes` evaluated to True, the test fails without real reason.
I'm looking for a way to replace the value of the returned function without actually running the function.
I have my own reason to use spy instead of mocking.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67734707/5389127

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mockito - difference between doReturn() and when()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353846/mockito-difference-between-doreturn-and-when)

Comment: You're using a spy, not a mock. I wouldn't expect the `when().doReturn()` to have any impact. Consider using a mock instead

Answer (score 1):

If you have reason to use a **spy**, then you need to use specific syntax to mock methods of it.

`when` doesn't work for spies. Instead use `doXxx.when(spy).method()`:

```scala
doReturn("value-to-replace")
  .when(spiedScalaSharedLibConfigManager)
  .functionToTest();
```

---

Another option is to use a **mock** rather than a **spy**.

---

References:

- [Mocking a Spy method with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689348/mocking-a-spy-method-with-mockito)
- [Mockito - difference between doReturn() and when()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353846/mockito-difference-between-doreturn-and-when)

Comment: I'm running your code
doReturn("value-to-replace")
  .when(spiedScalaSharedLibConfigManager)
  .functionToTest();

but when I'm running for the test scope
println(spiedScalaSharedLibConfigManager.functionToTest()) I'm receiving the same error.