# Use Mockito to Stub methods in the same class as the class under test (CUT)

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to test some legacy code using Mockito, and the method is a of type void.

I have stubbed out a lot of the calls to methods in other classes, this works fine.
However, I also need to be able to stub out certain calls to other methods inside the same class.

Currently this is not working.

e.g. My Class is like below:

```
public class Test {


    public Test(dummy dummy) {

    }

    public void checkTask(Task task, List <String> dependencyOnLastSuccessList) throws TaskException {
        callToOtherClass.method1 // This works fine, I can stub it using mockito

        updateAndReschedule(Long id, String message) // call to method in same class, I cannot stub it
    }

    public void updateAndReschedule(Long id, String message) {
        //method logic.....
    }
}
```

This is my testClass showing what I have at the minute:

```
@Test
public void testMyMethod() {
    Test testRef = new Test(taskJob);
    Test spy = spy (testRef);

    // when a particular method is called, return a specific  object
    when(callToOtherClass.method1).thenReturn(ObjectABC);

    //doNothing when my local method is called
    doNothing().when(spy).updateAndReschedule(1, "test");       
    //make method call
    spy.checkTask(ts, taskDependencies);

}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should instantiante testRef as follows:

```
Test testRef = new Test(taskJob) {

    public void updateAndReschedule(Long id, String message) {
        //do nothing
    }

};
```

No need for the spy.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. It works fine. In order to validate the test, I need to verify that the method was called, how would I do that as I have not instantiated it as a mockito class?

Comment: Now the quirks may start! :) You may have your reasons but in most cases it is not recommended to test the interna of your class. The goal of the test should be to validate the interaction of the class with its outside. Going too deep into verification of the internal stucture you end up with a test which makes refactoring more complicated. But to answer your question: just set a variable to a specific value from inside the overriddden method and assert for that. The variable must be final in this case, so a simlpe boolean won't do.

Comment: Thanks, yes it's legacy code so I cannot completely re factor it. How do I get the value out of the method. I tried using a getter method, but was still unable to see it when I tried to do the assert e.g.    private Boolean methodCalled = false;                  public void updateAndReschedule(Long id, String message) {
          methodCalled = true;
         }
         
         public boolean wasMethodCalled() {
             return methodCalled;
         }

Comment: Your approach doesn't work since the class Test doesn't expose this method. A hack-approach would be to do this: final boolean[] methodCalled = new boolean[1]; Test testRef = new Test(taskJob) {

    public void updateAndReschedule(Long id, String message) {
        methodCalled[0] = true;
    }

}; /*doStuff...*/ assertTrue(methodCalled[0]);

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion the spy object instead of mock.
Spy is a mock created as a proxy to an existing real object; some methods can be stubbed, while the unstubbed ones are forwarded to the covered object

The spy is more elegant than anonymous implementation of chosen methods

Look at the example:

[Mockito: Trying to spy on method is calling the original method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620103/mockito-trying-to-spy-on-method-is-calling-the-original-method)

the nice article about mockito You can read

http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/mockito