# Mockito tries to invoke method when I set behaviour for it

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, spy

I have following code line:

```
when(htmlEmailSpy.setFrom(anyString())).thenReturn(null);
```

Following code executes real `htmlEmailSpy.setFrom(...)` but it throws exception.

```
@Spy
HtmlEmail htmlEmailSpy = new HtmlEmail();
```

What do I wrong?

my aim - set new behaviour to spy object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved problem:

```
doReturn(null).when(htmlEmailSpy).setFrom(anyString());
```

took from: [Mockito: Trying to spy on method is calling the original method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11620196/2674303)