# Using when(methodX).thenReturn(resultY), does methodX get called?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, guice

I am having some difficulty mocking out the necessary dependencies for some unit tests.  I suspect I am not correctly understanding how to use the Mockito when().thenReturn().

Here is (hopefully the relevant) part of the code for the service I want to test:

```
@Singleton
public class AppointmentService {
    private DataConnector connector;

    @Inject
    public AppointmentService(DataConnector connector) {
        this.connector = connector;
    }

    public Appointment getAppointment(UriInfo uriInfo, String id) {
        HttpResponse response = connector.getAppointment(id);
        return validateResponse(response, uriInfo);
    }

    protected Appointment validateResponse(HttpResponse response, UriInfo uriInfo) {
        try {
            AppointmentWrapper appointmentWrapper = JacksonJsonUtility.readValue(response.getInputStream(), AppointmentWrapper.class);
            if(appointmentWrapper.getAppointment()!=null) {
                return appointmentConverterHelper(appointmentWrapper.getAppointment(), uriInfo.getPath());
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            throw new ResponseParsingException("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    protected Appointment appointmentConverterHelper(ExternalAppointmentModel appointmentDto, String uriPath) {
        if (appointmentDto == null) {
            throw new BrickworkQueryException("Got an invalid appointment object from Brickwork!");
        }

        Customer customer = new Customer(new Name(appointmentDto.getCustomer().getName()),
            appointmentDto.getCustomer().getEmail(),
            String.valueOf(appointmentDto.getCustomer().getCode()));

        return new Appointment(
            appointmentDto.getId(),
            customer);
    }

}
```

My understanding is that my unit test for this method should look something like this:

```
public class AppointmentServiceTest {

    private UriInfo mockUriInfo;
    private HttpResponse mockHttpResponse;

    @Mock
    private DataConnector mockDataConnector;

    @InjectMocks
    private AppointmentService appointmentService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockUriInfo();
        mockHttpResponse();
    }

    private void mockUriInfo() {
        mockUriInfo = mock(UriInfo.class);
        when(mockUriInfo.getRequestUri()).thenReturn(
            URI.create("http://localhost:8080"));
    }

    private void mockHttpResponse() {
        mockHttpResponse = mock(HttpResponse.class);
        when(mockHttpResponse.getInputStream()).thenReturn(
            IOUtils.toInputStream("{\"appointment\":{}}"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAppointment() throws Exception {
        when(mockDataConnector.getAppointmentById(Mockito.anyString())).
            thenReturn(mockHttpResponse);
        when(appointmentService.validateResponse(Mockito.any(HttpResponse.class), Mockito.any(UriInfo.class))).
            thenReturn(new Appointment());
        appointmentService.getAppointment(mockUriInfo, "12345");
        verify(mockDataConnector).getAppointment(Mockito.anyString());
    }
}
```

When I run my test I get a NullPointerException in the appointmentConverterHelper method when trying to call appointmentDto.getCustomer(), which is understandably empty.  As the code is running now, it seems to me that I will need to return an InputStream that contains a fully valid Appointment in my mockHttpResponse. Since I have `when(appointmentService.validateResponse(mockHttpResponse, mockUriInfo)).thenReturn(new Appointment());` shouldn't that pick up the `validateResponse` call and return the empty Appointment object rather than actually running validateResponse?

For reference, here is the stack trace on the Exception - line 140 of AppointmentServiceTest is the `when` statement above. Line 176 of the AppointmentsService is the `JacksonJsonUtility.readValue(response.getInputStream(), AppointmentWrapper.class);` line at the very beginning of the `validateResponse` method:

````
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.nike.appointmentservice.service.AppointmentsService.validatedResponse(AppointmentsService.java:176)
    at com.nike.appointmentservice.service.AppointmentsServiceTest.testGetAppointmentById(AppointmentsServiceTest.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)```
````

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace for the NPE?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice stack trace is added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue might be that the `when` statement is trying to match against a specific instance and is failing. To get started with Mockito unit tests you should replace the specific values in your `when` statements with Mockito placeholders that represent "anything". For example:

```
when(mockDataConnector.getAppointmentById(Mockito.anyString())).
  thenReturn(mockHttpResponse);

when(appointmentService.validateResponse(Mockito.any(HttpResponse.class), Mockito.any(UriInfo.class))).
        thenReturn(new Appointment());
```

When you have the basic unit tests working you can then add in more specific unit tests.

**Update**

I now notice that you are trying to test the `AppointmentService` class but you are also mocking out the `validateResponse` method within that class. I'm not enough of a Mockito expert to know if this is completely incorrect, but this is not the way that I use Mockito in my unit tests. The class I am testing is not mocked at all, but instead I mock out classes that it calls so as to simulate variable behaviour and see how the tested class responds.

I think you might need to mock the `JacksonJsonUtility` class (powermock helps with static classes) and remove the mock on the `validateResponse` method. You will need to construct the mock response to the `JacksonJsonUtility.readValue` method such that it contains everything that the AppointmentService class expects.

Comment: Made that edit, but looks like I'm still getting that NullPointerException inside the validateResponse method.  Do you think that means I'm still trying to match against a specific instance somehow?

Comment: Looks like the exception is getting thrown on the validateResponse `when` statement even when I comment out the actual `appointmentService.getAppointment` call.  So I think the problem is with the `when` statement I have trying to run the `validateResponse` method itself rather than just return the mocked response?

Comment: This is a pretty basic unit test fundamentals question, but wouldn't I want to mock out the `validateResponse` method to ensure I am testing only the `getAppointment` method?  Or is it valid to include multiple methods in the same unit test as long as they are in the same class?

Comment: I usually consider the "unit" to be a class - I will have a corresponding unit test class for each class to be tested. I use a code coverage tool (e.g. EMMA) to ensure that the entire class is "exercised" by the unit tests. It might depend on the particular project as to what constitutes a "unit" in that project - see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/unit-testing/570/introduction-to-unit-testing#t=201608240054306844858&a=remarks

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620103/mockito-trying-to-spy-on-method-is-calling-the-original-method), I think spying the AppointmentService is the way to go to allow me to mock out the `validateResponse` call.  So here's how my test looks now:

```
public class AppointmentServiceTest {

    private UriInfo mockUriInfo;
    private HttpResponse mockHttpResponse;

    @Mock
    private DataConnector mockDataConnector;

    @Spy
    private AppointmentsService appointmentsServiceSpy;

    @InjectMocks
    private AppointmentService appointmentService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        appointmentsServiceSpy = spy(appointmentsService);
        mockUriInfo();
        mockHttpResponse();
    }

    private void mockUriInfo() {
        mockUriInfo = mock(UriInfo.class);
        when(mockUriInfo.getRequestUri()).thenReturn(
            URI.create("http://localhost:8080"));
    }

    private void mockHttpResponse() {
        mockHttpResponse = mock(HttpResponse.class);
        when(mockHttpResponse.getInputStream()).thenReturn(
            IOUtils.toInputStream("{\"appointment\":{}}"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAppointment() throws Exception {
        when(mockDataConnector.getAppointmentById(Mockito.anyString())).
            thenReturn(mockHttpResponse);
        doReturn(new Appointment()).when(appointmentsServiceSpy).validateResponse(Mockito.any(HttpResponse.class), Mockito.any(UriInfo.class));
        appointmentServiceSpy.getAppointment(mockUriInfo, "12345");
        verify(mockDataConnector).getAppointmentById(Mockito.anyString());
    }
}
```

I'm still getting an exception on the actual `appointmentServiceSpy.getAppointment` call, but I think that is a separate issue related to how I am using the spy.  For the purposes of the original question, using a spy with a `doReturn().when()` statement resolves the issue of the method being erroneously called when using the `when().thenReturn()` statement.