# when mockito when thenReturn on spy not working?

Tags: mockito

from the doc: [Important gotcha on spying real objects!](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy)

```
List list = new LinkedList();
List spy = spy(list);

//Impossible: real method is called so spy.get(0) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException (the list is yet empty)
when(spy.get(0)).thenReturn("foo");

//You have to use doReturn() for stubbing
doReturn("foo").when(spy).get(0);
```

so, when does `when thenReturn` not working on `spy`?

[same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620103/mockito-trying-to-spy-on-method-is-calling-the-original-method)

Comment: The documentation of Mockito ( http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.18.3/org/mockito/Mockito.html ) has the following to say: "Sometimes it's impossible or impractical to use when(Object) for stubbing spies. Therefore for spies it is recommended to always use doReturn|Answer|Throw()|CallRealMethod family of methods for stubbing." The reasons are based on the Mockito internals, but I suggest starting with reading the documentation first, since it explains much.

Comment: I read the documentation,but still don't know when `when thenReturn ` not working? final method?static method? generic parameters?

Comment: so I read the `doReturn `method:[doReturn](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.18.3/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doReturn-java.lang.Object-).            I think there are three circumstances `when `not working: 1. void method-as doc said,2. real method may throw exception, I tested the this. 3. Overriding a previous exception-stubbing - as doc said.
correct me if wrong