# Real method getting called while setting up mock on spy

Tags: kotlin, mockito

It is driving me crazy why the real method getting called **during** setting up the mock on spy.

```
@Service
class A(){

 fun someMethod():String{
  println("inside real method")
  return "result"
 } 
}
```

test:

```
@SpyBean
private lateinit var a:A

@Test
fun test(){
 println("before mock")
 Mockito.`when`(a.someMethod()).doReturn("mock_result")
 println("empty test ended")
}
```

result:

> before mock
>  inside real method 
>  empty test ended

Once change from Sypbean to Mockbean then it works as expected:

```
@MockBean
private lateinit var a:A

@Test
fun test(){
 println("before mock")
 Mockito.`when`(a.someMethod()).doReturn("mock_result")
 println("empty test ended")
}
```

result:

> before mock
>  empty test ended

Why the real method getting called while just setting up the mock?
There is no direct method invocation at all in the code, the real test not even started.

edit:
I tried with doReturn,thenReturn,doAnswer,thenAnswer , the result is the same: if it is a spy then the real method getting called in the initializing phase

Comment: I can't see any invocation of `someMethod()` in your tests. When is it called? During the application instantiation? If so - the instantiation is done before even `test()` method is called, so `someMethod()` is called before it is stubbed in the `test()` method

Comment: @dey 
That is my problem it is not called at all. But still... mockito calls it.
edited the code adding before mock info printing

Comment: but is it called from y our code?

Comment: @dey nope, only created for testing purpose

Comment: in the meantime found the solution here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11620196/5454794
still.. totally nonsense

Comment: I added the answer with explanation why it helped (answer for better formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments, the answer from here helped: [Mockito: Trying to spy on method is calling the original method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620103/mockito-trying-to-spy-on-method-is-calling-the-original-method/11620196#11620196)

**Explanation:**

Having this line of code:

```
`when`(a.someMethod()).doReturn("mock_result")`
```

The code is executed in that way:

1. execute `a.someMethod()`
2. pass return value to `when()` method

But mockito is making his "magic" (I'm not aware of implementation details), to stub the next call of this method. But you already called the real method when stubbing.

That's why using different way of stubbing is not making this effect:

```
doReturn("mock_result").`when`(a).someMethod()
```

In This case, you are not calling `a.someMethod()`, but you tell mockito that it has to return "mock_result" when `someMethod()` is called.

Comment: To me, the (MISS-)behaviour of the two ways is the same: In both cases, the original method gets invoked on exactly that "when" line...

Comment: I just discovered, it works well on Java classes. It only does not work on classes written in Kotlin... (yes, for historical reasons, my project is mixing old Java and new Kotlin code)

Comment: I found my problem: The method being mocked MUST be "open" in Kotlin. In that case, both of the variants of the "when" statement work OK! So I am downvoting the accepted solution...

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents: I fell into the same problem. The mocking worked well on Java classes, but did not work well (as described above) on Kotlin classes. I found that both, the class being mocked, **and the method being mocked MUST be explicitly marked as "open"**. Then the mocking works as expected (both variants of the "when" statement work OK).

```
open class ToBeMocked {
    open fun toBeMocked() {} // The "open" keyword here is crucial
}
```

Comment: And a side note: I do not like to have to modify my code to be less strict, just to be able to test it :) To me this is a kind of violation of good programming habits...