# Mocking String.valueof()

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I'm testing my spring controller and trying to do the following

Controller

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication();
    String role = String.valueOf(authentication.getAuthorities());
    if(role.contains("user")) {
        ...
    }
```

Test

```
@Test
public void testLoginUser() throws Exception {
    User user = new User();
    user.setLogin("user");
    user.setRoleid(1L);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user,user));
    when(String.valueOf(Collection.class)).thenReturn("user");
```

But I get

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException
```

I need my `if` block to be `true` and execute.
Is there any way it can be done?

Comment: Did you look at PowerMock? See https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic and https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockFinal .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because
1. `String` class is final and you cant mock final classes with Mockito.
2. `String.valueOf` is a static metod and you cant mock static method with Mockito

From [**Mockito FAQ**](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/FAQ)

> What are the limitations of Mockito
>
> ```
> Needs java 1.5+
> Cannot mock final classes    // String is Final
> Cannot mock static methods... // String.valueOf is static
> ```

Either mock `authentication.getAuthorities()` method or use [**Powermock**](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/).

This [**link**](http://www.michaelminella.com/testing/how-to-mock-static-methods.html) might help.

Answer (score 1):

`String.valueOf` is a static method and is not mocked by Mockito. Your expression will simply resolve to a String instance with the value `"class java.util.Collection"`.

[Why does Mockito not mock static methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482315/why-does-mockito-not-mock-static-methods).