# Mockito UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am getting a

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

NumberFormatCustom.toFixed(DI)Ljava/lang/String;

NumberFormatCustom.toFixed(Native Method)

```
@Test
public void prepareDeForFormTest() {
    assertEquals("", FormHelper.prepareDeForForm(null));
    Double myDouble = 123.;
    when(NumberFormatCustom.getIntegerInstance(true).format(myDouble)).thenReturn("123");
    assertEquals(FormHelper.prepareDeForForm(myDouble), NumberFormatCustom.getIntegerInstance(true).format(myDouble));
}
```

The method **toFix** shown in the error is called in the **format** method, do I have to mock the result of toFix as well ? How can I do that ?

Comment: I don't think Mockito works well with static methods... See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482315/why-does-mockito-not-mock-static-methods for example

Answer (score 0):

As `jny` states, `Mockito` cannot mock static methods. Try `PowerMock` or `JMockit`