# Mokito don't return my value instance call database

Tags: java, junit

I tried to make a junit test for my class, I would like to Mock my Cache variable when calling the methot "get". My variable cache is an instance of CacheManger who call my database. But i don't know how to test my method. anyone got an idea ?
Thank's for your answer !

```
private static Cache<String, Integer> cache;

private static final String QUERY = "EXEC myQuery";

public static Integer getLanguageId(String language) {
    if (language == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Integer languageId = cache.get(language);
    if (languageId == null) {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    return languageId;
}

static void configureCache() {
    if (cache == null) {
        //CacheManager call database
        cache = CacheManager.getInstance()
                .createCache(QUERY, new RuleConfigurer.StringAndIntegerRowMapper());
    }
}
```

Comment: Mockito mocks objects, not classes. If everything is static and doesn't use dependency injection, you'll have a hard time using Mockito.

Comment: From where does the configureCache() method called? If it is not called in the constructor you can white box a mocked cache. If it's called in the constructor you will need to use powermock to mock the CacheManger itself.

Comment: My method configureCache() is not alled on my constructor, but from an other class !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am following your question completely or not. But to verify static methods you can use `PowerMockito`. That is the correct way of doing it.

You can see examples [here](https://automationrhapsody.com/verify-static-method-called-powermock/).

Also see one sample class I created below

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(DriverManager.class)
public class Mocker {

    @Test
    public void shouldVerifyParameters() throws Exception {

        //given
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(DriverManager.class);
        BDDMockito.given(DriverManager.getConnection(...)).willReturn(...);

        //when
        sut.execute(); // System Under Test (sut)

        //then
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
        DriverManager.getConnection(...);

    }
```

More Information

[Why doesn't Mockito mock static methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482315/why-does-mockito-not-mock-static-methods)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple unit test for your class.

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import javax.cache.Cache;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({SomeClass.class})
public class SomeClassTest {

    @Before
    public void setup() throws IllegalAccessException {
        Cache<String, Integer> cache = Mockito.mock(Cache.class);
        Mockito.when(cache.get("Language1")).thenReturn(1);

        Field field = PowerMockito.field(SomeClass.class, "cache");
        field.set(SomeClass.class, cache);
    }

    @Test
    public void should_return_1_when_Language1_is_the_input() throws Exception {
        Integer expectedResult = 1;
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult, SomeClass.getLanguageId("Language1"));
    }

    @Test
    public void should_return_null_when_input_is_null() throws Exception {
        Assert.assertNull(SomeClass.getLanguageId(null));
    }

    @Test (expected = Exception.class)
    public void should_throw_exception_when_unknown_language_is_input() throws Exception {
        SomeClass.getLanguageId("UnknownLanguage");
    }
}
```