# How to Mock an Enum Class using Mockito 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit4

This application is developed using Spring Boot. I have a controller class named BridgeController where I'm performing a POST call.

```java
@PostMapping(path = STATUS, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response status(@RequestBody final Request request) {
    return this.bridgeService.status(request);
}
```

Service Class named BridgeService where it is having a method named status and inside this method, I have used "Status" which is an enum class.

```java
@Override
public Response status(final request request) {
    final String id = request.getId();
    final Response response = Response.build();
    final Status status = Status.fromId(mappings.getId());
    if (null == status) {
        response.setStatus(RequestStatus.FAILURE);
        response.setStatusMsg(
                "Unable to find a valid mapping for the status id : " + mappings.getStatusId());
    } else {
        response.setResponse(status.getName());
    }
    return response;
}
```

This is my Test Class

```java
public class BridgeControllerTest extends BaseTest {
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext context;

    @InjectMocks
    BridgeController bridgeController;

    @MockBean
    request request;

    @Mock
    Status status;

    @Mock
    BridgeService bridgeService;

    ObjectMapper objmapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Before
    public  void setUp(){
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void statusSuccessTest() throws JsonProcessingException, Exception{  
        Mappings mappings = Mappings.build();
        when(statusRequest.getId()).thenReturn("12345");
        when(Status.fromId(mappings.getStatusId())).thenReturn(status);
        MvcResult result=this.mockMvc.perform(post("/status")
                .content(objmapper.writeValueAsString(request))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
        String resultContent = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();      
        AppResponse appResponse = objmapper.readValue(resultContent, Response.class);
        assertEquals("Request processed successfully", Response.getStatusMsg());
        Assert.assertTrue(Response.getStatus().getValue()=="SUCCESS");  
    }
}
```

My Enum is
public enum Status {

```
PENDING(1, "PENDING"), CONFIRMED(2, "CONFIRMED"), DECLINED(3, "DECLINED");

private final int id;

private final String name;

Status(final int id, final String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

@JsonCreator
public static Status fromId(final int id) {
    for (final Status status : Status.values()) {
        if (status.getId() == id) {
            return status;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}
Getting an exception at `when(AAStatus.fromId(requestMappings.getStatusId())).thenReturn(null);`

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
    Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
    Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
```

Can anyone help me in fixing this issue?

Comment: You cannot mock an enum.

Comment: Yes, you can't create a mock for a `final` class, and an `enum` is just a special case of a `final` class.

Comment: Why would you possibly want to mock an Enum class? Why not use the Enum itself?

Comment: I got to know that  we can mock an enum using Mockito 2

Comment: Consider that your `static` method is never supposed to return `null` in a valid scenario. What are you trying to test here?

Comment: For valid scenario static method is not returning null, Its returning status reference here I'm checking that status is not null. when(Status.fromId(mappings.getStatusId())).thenReturn(status);  Here fromId method is a static method so I'm unable to mock it. Is there any way to mock this

Comment: It is possible for a while now: 
[39. Mocking final types, enums and final methods (Since 2.1.0)](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.28.1/org/mockito/Mockito.html#Mocking_Final)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to mock static methods. You won't be able

[Why doesn't Mockito mock static methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482315/why-doesnt-mockito-mock-static-methods)

You might want to use Dependency Injection more broadly. Anyway, if still you really want to follow that path, use Powermockito

[Mocking static methods with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito)