# Mockito testcases (getting exception - Missing method invocation)

Tags: spring, junit, mockito

I am new to the Mockito. I am trying to write test case for following restcontroller method.

```
    @ResponseBody   
    @RequestMapping(value = Constants.PATH_NAME, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseData abc(@RequestBody RequestData requestData, HttpServletRequest request)
            throws Exception
        request.setAttribute("req", requestData);
        if (Validation.numberValiadtion(requestData.getNumber())) {  // where Validation is the static  class of external jar
            LOGGER.info("Number validated successfully--");
        } else {
            String errorMessage = Constants.INVALID_NUMBER;
            throw new NumberNotFoundException(errorMessage);
        }
        ResponseData reponseData = service.getScheduleData(requestData); //service is autowired

        return reponseData;
    }
```

and my testcase is

```
 @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.Silent.class)

 public class ApplicationTest {

 @Mock
 AbcService service;

  @Mock
  HttpServletRequest httpReq;

 @Test
  public void abcSuccess() throws Exception {

  SampleController restController = Mockito.mock(SampleController.class);
  Validation validation = Mockito.mock(Validation.class);

 RequestData req = new RequestData();
 ResponseData respData = new ResponseData();
 Mockito.when(restController.abc(req, httpReq)).thenReturn(respData); 
Mockito.when(validation.numberValiadtion("467")).thenReturn(true); --err line

 Mockito.when(service.getData(req)).thenReturn(respData);

  }
}
```

And the errortrace-

```
  org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
  when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.                                       
   For example:
   when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

   Also, this error might show up because:
  1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
  Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
  Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
  2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
```

Could you please help me out to solve the issue.Validation calss is the static class (in external Jar)

Comment: Is `service` a mock ?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned @mock  . Getting  exception with validation class.

Comment: It shouldn't . Could you update the question with the entire test class code or alteast a minimum reproducible example ?

Comment: I have edited code. Please help.

Comment: If `Validation` is a framework class , please share the path else share the `Validation` class code

Comment: No. It's normal static class where we have written numbers validation with some rules.

Comment: Please read through this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4482315/4214241) to understand why static methods cannot be mocked. Please check if there is a real need to mock  `validation.numberValiadtion()` and I think the test will work as expected without that mock.

Comment: do  I need  to  use  real implementation?

Comment: If my understanding is correct , it is just a helper method to validate a number. Have you realized that the main issue with this test is that , you are mocking the class under test itself , which fails the whole purpose of this unit test.