# If I have Mockito.Spy()/@Spy doesn't work properly with FieldSetter ? How to work use @Spy and FieldSetter Combinedly?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

If I use @Spy, it will help me to mock methods. but it doesn't work for private variable initialization

```
FieldSetter.setField(discoveryService, discoveryService.getClass().getDeclaredField("discoveryURL"), discoveryUrl);
```

If I remove @spy, FieldSetter works to initialize mock private variables.
My code with @spy:

```
           @InjectMocks
/*line 5*/ @Spy
    private Class object;
     
    @Test
    void getFetchDiscoveryTest() throws IOException, NoSuchFieldException {

        String discoveryUrl = "https://ffc-onenote.officeapps.live.com/hosting/discovery";

/*line 15*/ FieldSetter.setField(object, object.getClass().getDeclaredField("discoveryURL"), discoveryUrl);
/*line 16*/ doThrow(IOException.class).when(object).getBytes(any());
/*line 17*/ when(object.getBytes(any())).thenThrow(new IOException("IO issue"));
        assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> object.getWopiDiscovery());
```

here if I putted line #5, then line #15 not works and line #16 working good.
why If i have @spy, FieldSetter not works.  how to make FieldSetter working for @spy as well ?

Comment: As far as I know, Mockito won't work with static methods / variables. ([see here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482315/why-doesnt-mockito-mock-static-methods)) You might have to use PowerMock on top.

Comment: What do you mean by "FieldSetter not works"? It throws exception? Do nothing?

Comment: This is a demonstration that you need to modify your API. In particular, it seems you should be using _dependency injection_ and possibly passing in the URL as a constructor parameter.

Comment: regarding dependency injection:  am getting private variable initialisation from property file. hence it should be initialised in test as well, since it already present in application.yml.    FieldSetter not works means :  that private variable value still not initialised , even though we are setting it via fieldsetter. but no error or exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use FieldSetter, use ReflectionTestUtils.setField() and it will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

you can Inject values for private attributes of an instance using `org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils`

```
@Service
public class SampleDiscoveryService{

    @Value("${props.discoveryUrl}")
   private String discoveryUrl;
}
```

Let's say above is service class, the value for `discoveryUrl` can be injected using

```
   @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class SampleDiscoveryServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private SampleDiscoveryService sampleDiscoveryService = null;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
       ReflectionTestUtils.setField(sampleDiscoveryService, "discoveryUrl", "https://ffc-onenote.officeapps.live.com/hosting/discovery");
    }
```