# How to set declared fields after spying the system under test(sut)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

Apparently, when I try to spy the "System Under Test" object (sut) in my TestClass, while also trying to set/get a declared field from sut's class using reflection, it throws java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: fieldName

I'm trying to inject mocks manually in the below code, but I've tried the same with @InjectMocks with @Spy too and got nothing different :

```
public class TestedClass {
    public SomeClass1 field1;
    public SomeClass2 field2;

    // methods to be tested
}
```

TestClass ---

```
public class TestClass {
    private TestedClass sut;
    private SomeClass1 field1;
    private SomeClass2 field2;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {
        sut = Mockito.spy(new TestedClass());
        field1 = Mockito.mock(SomeClass1.class);
        field2 = Mockito.mock(SomeClass2.class);
        setSutField("field1", field1);
        setSutField("field2", field2);
    }

    private void setSutField(String fieldName, Object value) throws Exception {
        Field field = sut.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(sut, value);
    } 

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        // use fields 1 and 2 here
    }
}
```

At the end, I want to stub one of the protected methods in the TestedClass so that I can return a mock. For this, sut needs to be spied/mocked.

**EDIT:** Already tried solutions -

1. FieldSetter, but it doesn't work for me.
2. My application uses EJB and not Spring framework, so I can't use ReflectionTestUtils : [If I have Mockito.Spy()/@Spy doesn't work properly with FieldSetter ? How to work use @Spy and FieldSetter Combinedly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62807985/if-i-have-mockito-spy-spy-doesnt-work-properly-with-fieldsetter-how-to-wor)
3. @Spy with @InjectMocks on sut, throws this error :

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Cannot create a @Spy for 'sut' field because the *instance* is missing

**Note:** The TestedClass is legacy code, so can't be changed much.

Many Thanks!

Comment: You can just use `when(sut.getField1()).thenReturn(field1))`? Note that it's usually not a good sign if you have to use `Spy` at all.

Comment: That's the problem. If I "@Spy" the sut, it throws : org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Cannot create a "@Spy" for 'sut' field because the *instance* is missing. Adding this to the post.

Comment: Oh, I missed that you tried to spy the object you're actually testing. That's not only not a good sign but pretty much out of the question, it makes your test pretty much worthless altogether. I don't see why you're writing tests for a class you can't even change though.

Comment: @daniu Worthless because sut is the one which is supposed to be tested and not spied/mocked? Unfortunately, the sut class uses a setter injection for a particular bean in a method to be tested and not a separate factory. I can't think of any other way except stubbing that setter so that a mock can be returned in its place.

Comment: Yes, maybe "worthless" is too strong a word, but certainly "not reliable" because you're testing different code than what's run. But if it uses setter injection, there must be setters, so just call those?