# some questions on unit tests and rhino mocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, mocking, rhino-mocks

I am new to writing unit tests so learning as I go along. I am using Rhino Mocks with MsTest frameworks and have some questions.

Where can I find some documentation on rhino mocks, outlining its features with explanations, so I can print off and examine?

I have seen numerous examples of the 2 following techniques regarding expectations, which is the better or more apt for a particular situation?

```
Expect.Call( delegate { mockTestClass.MethodToMock(param) } ).Return(true);
```

or

```
var mockTestClass = MockRepository.GenerateMock<TestClass>();

mockTestClass.Expect( m => m.MethodToMock(param) ).Return( true );
```

Next I am wondering what the difference between stubbing and mocking a class is and what should be used in which scenarios?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: [The Art of Unit Testing](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Art-Unit-Testing-Examples-NET/dp/1933988274) is a really good book for learning about unit testing - it's what I started with. It goes into the use of mocks and stubs too.

Answer (score 4):

> Where can I find some documentation on rhino mocks, outlining its features with explanations, so I can print off and examine?

Rhino Mocks docs are [here](http://ayende.com/Wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Documentation.ashx) and a good wiki is [here](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino%20Mocks%203.5.ashx). In general, be careful with anything mentioning versions 3.3 or lower, as it will be somewhat outdated.

> which is the better or more apt for a particular situation?

The second way is more "fluent" and recommended.

> what the difference between stubbing and mocking

Here are some resources about this:

- [What's the difference between a mock & stub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459287/testing-mock-vs-stub)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object#Mocks.2C_fakes_and_stubs
- http://codebetter.com/jameskovacs/2009/02/10/mocks-vs-stubs/
- http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html

BTW if you're just getting started with these concepts I think you'll be better off using NUnit and Moq. [Here's an introduction](http://cgeers.com/2011/05/07/nunit-moq/) with examples.

Comment: +1 - hope you don't mind that I added another Rhino link to your answer

Comment: Thanks very much for the feedback. Can I ask why you suggested " I think you'll be better off using NUnit and Moq"?

Comment: @amateur : NUnit is simpler and you'll find lots of info, Moq is newer than Rhino.Mocks and better maintained/documented.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that specific method was called and return value does not matter I would suggest using [AAA syntax](http://ayende.com/blog/3318/rhino-mocks-arrange-act-assert-syntax) and `AssertWasCalled()` method:

```
// Arrange
var mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ICustomType>();
var service = new MyService(mock);

// Act
service.DoSomething();

// Assert 
// ensures that SomeMethod of the mock was called 
// whilst service.DoSomething() call
mock.AssertWasCalled(m => m.SomeMethod());
```

Difference between stubs and mocks from RhinoMocks framework perspectives are following:

- Expectations can be set for both Mocks and Stubs but they are verified only for Mocks, for instance you would not be able specify `Repeat().Any()` and so on for stub
- Stubs never fail when accessing methods or properties, all properties and methods return `default(T)` for given return type `T`, properties of Stub is normal properties

More details regarding difference between Mocks and Stubs see in a good set of links provided in the Mauricio's answer, I would suggest Martin Fowler's work.