# How to mock SendGrid

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mstest, sendgrid

I am trying to write a unit test for a method I wrote which sends out an email with SendGrid.
My method is something like this:

```
public async Task SendEmail(TemplatedMailMessage emailMessage)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emailMessage.Html) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emailMessage.From.ToString()) || !emailMessage.To.Any())
    {
        throw new Exception("Html, From or To is empty");
    }

    try
    {
        // Send the email
        await this.TransportWeb.DeliverAsync(emailMessage.GetSendGridMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //do stuff
    }

    //log success
}
```

the TransportWeb is a property which is set in my constructor through a parameter so I can create a mock object.

```
public EmailManager(Web transportWeb = null)
{
    this.TransportWeb = transportWeb ?? SetupSendGrid();
}
```

In my test method I am trying to mock the TransportWeb (of type SendGrid.Web) property:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task SendEmail_ValidEmailTemplateAndNoParameters_EmailIsSent()
    {
        //ARRANGE
        var templatedMailmessage = new Mock<TemplatedMailMessage>();
        var transportWeb = new Mock<Web>();
        transportWeb.SetupAllProperties();
        transportWeb.Setup(x => x.DeliverAsync(It.IsAny<ISendGrid>()));
        var emailManager = new EmailManager(transportWeb.Object);

        //ACT
        await emailManager.Send(templatedMailmessage.Object);

        //ASSERT
        transportWeb.Verify(x => x.DeliverAsync(It.IsAny<ISendGrid>()), Times.Once());
    }
```

However, I get the following error:

> Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: x =>
>   x.DeliverAsync

Does anybody have an idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay I fixed it :)

You should not use the Web class but ITransport interface:

```
var transport = new Mock<ITransport>();
transport.SetupAllProperties();
transport.Setup(x => x.DeliverAsync(It.IsAny<SendGridMessage>())).ReturnsTask();

var em = new EmailManager(transport.Object);
```

I also used the [extensions methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16462315/1200072) created by [Simon V](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1642427/simon-v).

Comment: In addition you can have a look at [shims](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549176.aspx) . Cool isolation framework from MS which can mock whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

If your tests simply want to check that an email has been sent, then you could have your own `TestSendGridClient` that implements `ISendGridClient`.
The only method to implement is `SendEmailAsync` which adds the email to an internal collection.

```
public List<string> emails = new List<string>();

public async Task<Response> SendEmailAsync(SendGridMessage msg, 
CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    emails.AddRange(msg.Personalizations[0].Tos.Select(x => x.Email));

    return await Task.FromResult(new Response(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, null, null));
}
```

Then in your tests you would just check that the expected email is in the emails list.