# How do I set a property on a mocked object using Mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a scenario where I have to set a property of a mocked object as follows:

```
SlingHttpRequest slingHttpRequest= mock(SlingHttpRequest);
slingHttpRequest.setAttribute("search", someObject);
```

When I try to print this attribute I get `null`.  How do I set this property?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You don't normally set properties on your mocked objects; instead, you do some specific thing when it's invoked.

```
when(slingHttpRequest.getAttribute("search")).thenReturn(someObject);
```

Comment: _+1 "Mocks are there to do, not to represent!".

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you're misusing your mock `SlingHttpRequest`.

Mockito requires you to wire up your mock's properties before you use them in your test scenarios, i.e.:

`Mockito.when(slingHttpRequest.getAttribute("search")).thenReturn(new Attribute());`

You cannot call the `setAttribute(final Attribute a)` method during the test like so:

`slingHttpRequest.setAttribute(someObject)`;

If you do this, when the test runs, `getAttribute()` will return `null`.

Incidently, if the code you are unit testing is going to call a setter on your mock in this way, do not use a mock. Use a [stub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459287/whats-the-difference-between-a-mock-stub).

Answer (score 0):

Mock object is not where you store data, it's for you to teach the behavior when its methods are invoked.

try this: https://www.google.com/search?q=mockito+example&oq=mockito+example&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6790j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: You do answer the question, but the link doesn't add much more than what could be found in a Google search.  Consider editing it or adding examples.

Comment: What I meant was that the examples for this topic can be found easily by a simple key word

Comment: Then it's honestly more of a comment than an answer, to be frank.

Comment: @Makoto I disagree.  OP is mocking a class that maybe shouldn't be mocked.  It's not clear to me whether `SlingHttpRequest` is a class or an interface - I can't find it in the sling docs.  But if it's a class, then it seems to be about storing data, not executing functionality; and that implies that there is nothing to be gained by mocking it.  So the first sentence of this post is the correct answer - it's just somewhat let down by the google link, but still worth a +1.

Answer (score -1):

I'm probable 7 years late for the party, but I still would like to contribute.

You CAN set class property using the Whitebox from powermock:

```
Whitebox.setInternalState(mockedClass, "internalField", "Value to be returned")
```