# Automatically generate stubbed modules in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, jestjs

I'm moving my JavaScript test code from Jest to Mocha. One nice feature of Jest is that it automatically generated [stubs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17810004/388951) for your modules. These stubs implement the same API as the originals, but all their functions return `undefined`. Exported classes are also stubbed, i.e. they have all the same methods as the original, but the return undefined:

```js
// mymodule.js
var MyClass = function() { this.foo = 42; };
MyClass.prototype.getFoo = function() { return this.foo; };
module.exports = {
  myclass: MyClass,
  myfunction: function() { return 42; }
};
```

```js
// __tests__/mymodule-test.js
var mm = require('../mymodule');  // Jest auto-mocks this module.

describe('test', function() {
  it('functions and constructors are mocked', function() {
    expect(mm.myfunction()).toEqual(undefined);  // function is stubbed
    var mc = new mm.myclass();
    expect(mc.getFoo()).toEqual(undefined);  // fn on prototype is stubbed.
  });
});
```

For various reasons, I'm moving over to MochaJS but I'd like to keep this stubbing behavior. I can inject stubs for modules using proxyquire. But I need to define the stubs myself.

What I'd like is a function which which takes a Node module and returns something like the Jest auto-mocked version of the module. Jest's code to do this is in [moduleMocker.js](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/src/lib/moduleMocker.js). I've written some code of my own to do this (included below). But it's quite tricky and doesn't feel like code I should be writing.

Is there a standard library for doing this?

Here's what I've written:

```js
// stubber.js
var U = require('underscore');

function replaceFunctionsWithStubs(rootObj) {
  var replacedObjs = [];  // array of [original, replacement] pairs.

  function previousReplacement(obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < replacedObjs.length; i++) {
      if (replacedObjs[i][0] == obj) {
        return replacedObjs[i][1];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  function replacer(obj) {
    var t = typeof(obj);
    if (t != 'function' && t != 'object') {
      // Simple data.
      return obj;
    }

    // Return previous mock to break circular references.
    var prevRep = previousReplacement(obj);
    if (prevRep) return prevRep;

    if (t == 'function') {
      var f = function() {};
      replacedObjs.push([obj, f]);
      if (!U.isEmpty(obj.prototype)) {
        // This might actually be a class. Need to stub its prototype, too.
        var newPrototype = replacer(obj.prototype);
        for (var k in newPrototype) {
          f.prototype[k] = newPrototype[k];
        }
      }

      // Stub any properties the function might have.
      for (var k in obj) {
        f[k] = replacer(obj[k]);
      }
      return f;
    } else if (typeof(obj) == 'object') {
      // TODO: Do I need to handle arrays differently?
      var newObj = {};
      replacedObjs.push([obj, newObj]);

      for (var k in obj) {
        newObj[k] = replacer(obj[k]);
      }
      return newObj;
    } else {
      return obj;  // string, number, null, undefined, ...
    }
  }

  return replacer(rootObj);
}

module.exports = function(m) {
  return replaceFunctionsWithStubs(m);
};
```

Comment: I really feel Jest should have focused on doing JUST this. With another library to implement the rest of Jest's features. The reason I don't want to use Jest is because it forces you to use Jasmine etc

Comment: My eventual solution to this issue was to [switch to Mocha](http://www.hammerlab.org/2015/02/14/testing-react-web-apps-with-mocha/) for testing. For a more recent React project, I've been using Mocha in-browser for testing. Once you're in-browser, tools like sinon work without the headaches mentioned in this question.

Comment: have you been able to find a way to automatically mock required modules? I know sinon can help, but to my knowledge it's not implicitly automatic

Comment: You might be able to override `require` with a stub-generating version, but frankly I think automatic mocking is a bad idea. You should mock a whitelist of modules, rather than mock all but a blacklist of modules. Mocking everything means that internal refactors will break all your tests.