# How to program behavior of a void method with Mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I have a Controller class with something like this

```
public void create(int a, int b){
     //do something
}
```

Now i want to mock the Controller class and call a certain method for exmaple doCustomCreate() when the create Method of my mocked Controller class is called.

My test would ´look something like this

```
Controller ctrlMock = mock(Controller.class);
//PseudoCode: when(isCalled(ctrlMock.create(a,b)).doCall(doCustomCreate());
```

I only read about mocking methods with input and return values, so i wondered if this is possible?

Edit: Updated the Question

Comment: The list is a private field of the mocked object. Why do you care about what it contains? It seems you want the mock to do what it would do if it was not mocked.

Comment: google "mockito void method", first result

Comment: @JBNizet actually technically it's a package level protected. Thoguh I doubt it's actually used as such in the authors code.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to use a mock for a different purpose than what it's really intended for. Please could you explain a bit more what you want to test?

Comment: @Ray Why so? I use Mockito for the exact purpose as Mockito was designed.

Comment: i updated the question maybe it is now a bit more clear

Comment: @Gobliins i think @Ray means you might want to consider using a `stub`, not a `mock`. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17810004/3380951) explains the difference.

Answer (score 5):

Just use this API for void methods :

```
doAnswer(doCustomCreate()).when(ctrlMock).create(a,b);
```

Or with `BDDMockito` :

```
willAnswer(doCustomCreate()).given(ctrlMock).create(a,b);
```

Where `doCustomCreate()` returns an `Answer` (that returns `null`). Note I used `Void` just to indicate this answer don't return anything.

```
public Answer<Void> doCustomCreate() {
    return new Answer<Void>() {
        public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
            // your stuff
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Note giving behavior to a mock is somehow a rocky path for maintainability of tests, as it means the tested component is not tested in pure controlled environment / isolation.

Comment: This could be what i am looking for, i will try this out.

Comment: @Gobliins I've updated the answer for more complete usage info.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to override the mock's behavior for a certain method. The solution for this is using a so-called *spy* (AKA partial mock) instead of a mock: http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#16

Comment: No, this is the opposite of what i want to do.I don't want to call the real method, for what would i need a mock then? i want to call my own method. If you would replace the 'when(mock.someMethod()).thenCallRealMethod();' by 'when(mock.someMethod()).thenCallMyCustomMethod();' then it would be logical.