# Test Environment with Mocked REST API

Tags: python, rest

Lets say I have a very simple web app which is presented as blue if the current president is a democrat and red if they are a republican. A REST API is used to get the current president, via the endpoint:

```
/presidents/current
```

which currently returns the json object:

```
{name: "Donald Trump", party: "Republican"}
```

So when my page loads I call the endpoint and I show red or blue depending on who is returned.

I wish to test this HTML/javascript page and I wish to mock the back-end so that I can control from within the test environment the API responses. For example:

```
def test_republican():
    # configure the response for this test that the web app will receive when it connects to this endpoint
    configure_endpoint(
        "/presidents/current", 
        jsonify(
            name="Donald Trump",
            party="Republican"
        )
    )  

    # start the web app in the browser using selenium 
    load_web_app(driver, "http://localhost:8080")  

    e = driver.find_element_by_name("background")
    assert(e.getCssValue("background-color") == "red")


def test_democrat():
    # configure the response for this test that the web app will receive when it connects to this endpoint
    configure_endpoint(
        "/presidents/current", 
        jsonify(
            name="Barack Obama",
            party="Democrat"
        )
    )    

    # start the web app in the browser using selenium 
    load_web_app(driver, "http://localhost:8080")  

    e = driver.find_element_by_name("background")
    assert(e.getCssValue("background-color") == "blue")
```

So the question is how should I implement the function `configure_endpoint`() and what libraries can you recommend me?

Answer (score 4):

As @Kie mentioned, `configure_endpoint` implementation won't be enough, if you're going to stub the whole server-side within Selenium Python code. You would need a web server or whatever that will response via HTTP to requests from within testing environment.

It looks like the question is partially about testing of client-side code. What I see is that you're trying to make unit-test for client-side logic, but use integration testing suite in order to check this logic (it's strange).

The main idea is as follows.

You're trying to test client-side code. So, let's make mocks client-side too! Because this part of code is completely client-side related stuff.

If you actually want to have mocks, not stubs (watch the difference here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3459491/882187) it is a better way to mock out HTTP requests inside your Javascript code. Just because you're testing a client-side piece of code, not some parts of server-side logic.

Having it isolated from whatever server-side is - is a great idea that you would love when your project become grow, while more and more endpoints will be appearing.

For example, you can use the following approach:

```
var restResponder = function() { // the original responder your client-side app will use
  this.getCurrentPresident = function(successCallback) {
    $.get('/presidents/current', callback);
  }
};

var createMockResponder = function(president, party){ // factory that creates mocks
  var myPresident = president;
  var myParty = party;

  return function() {
    this.getCurrentPresident = function (successCallback) {
      successCallback({"name": myPresident, "party": myParty});
    }
  };
}

// somewhere swap the original restResponder with new mockResponder created by 'createMockResponder'

// then use it in your app:

function drawColor(restResponder, backgroundEl) {
  restResponder.getCurrentPresident(function(data){
     if (data.party == "Democrat") $(backgroundEl).style('background-color', 'blue')
     else if (data.party == "Republican") $(backgroundEl).style('background-color', 'red')
     else console.info('Some strange response from server... Nevermind...');
  });
}
```

Practically, this implementation depends on what do you have at the client-side as a framework. If `jQuery`, then my example is enough, but it looks very wordy. In case you have something more advanced, like `AngularJS`, you can do the same in 2-3 lines of code:

```
// Set up the mock http service responses
$httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
// backend definition common for all tests
authRequestHandler = $httpBackend.when('GET', '/auth.py')
                                 .respond({userId: 'userX'}, {'A-Token': 'xxx'});
```

Check out the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

If you're still stick to the idea, that you need mocks inside Selenium tests, please 
try this project: https://turq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

It serves with Python DSL for describing REST responders.
Using `turq` your mocks will look as follows:

```
path('/presidents/current').json({'name':'Barack Obama', 'party': 'Democrat'}, jsonp=False)
```

Also, I would recommend to try stubs instead of mocks and use this Python module: `mock-server` https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock-server/0.3.7
You are required to create the directory layout containing corresponding pre-populated JSON responses and to add some boilerplate code in order to make the `mock-server` respond on 'localhost:8080'. The directory layout for your example will look like this:

```
stub_obama/
  presidents/
    current/
      GET_200.json      # will contain {"name": "Barack Obama", "party": "Democrat"}
stub_trump/
  presidents/
    current/
      GET_200.json      # will contain {"name": "Donald Trump", "party": "Republican"}
```

But the `mock_server` is based on Tornado, it is very heavy solution for using in tests I think.

I hope, my answer is helpful and informative. Welcome to discuss it! I made tons of projects with Selenium, big and small tests, tested client-side and server-side.

Answer (score 2):

I would use tornado web framework.

```
import json
import functools
import operator
from tornado import ioloop, web, gen
from tornado.options import define, options

define("data_file", default='default/mock.json', type=str)

class Handler(web.RequestHandler):

    def data_received(self, chunk):
        pass

    def initialize(self, data):
        self.data = data

    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        path = self.request.path.split("/")[1:]
        path = functools.reduce(
            operator.add,
            [[k, v[0].decode("utf-8")] for k, v in         self.request.query_arguments.items()],
            path
        )

        try:
            self.write(functools.reduce(operator.getitem, path, self.data))
        except KeyError:
            self.set_status(404)


class Application(web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        data = {}
        with open(options.data_file) as data_file:
            data = json.load(data_file)

        handlers = [
            ('(.*)', Handler, {"data": data})
        ]
        settings = dict(
            gzip=True,
            static_hash_cache=True,
        )
        web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)


    def main():
        io_loop = ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
        backend_application = Application()
        backend_application.listen(8001)
        io_loop.start()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

This is a code I used for mocking a REST-API which is a standalone script, but it can be embedded into your test environment as well.

I defined a JSON file which defines the different path components and what should be returned. Like this:

```
{
    "presidents": {
        "current": {
            "name": "Donald Trump", 
            "party": "Republican"
        }
    }
}
```

I saved this to a mock.json and called the script with a parameter `mock_rest.py --data-file="./mock.json"`.

I hope that gives you a starting point and a good example.

Answer (score 1):

If your `load_web_app` function uses the [`requests` library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to access the REST API, using [`requests-mock`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-mock) is a convenient way to fake that library's functionality for test purposes.

Comment: No load_web_app() simply loads the html/js file in the browser using selenium. I need to mock the backend by creating a api server to which the web app connects to. This mock server should be configurable from within the test environment.

Comment: Do you have a good reason to want to isolate the system under test that far away from the tested client business logic rather than much closer to it? (I'm assuming you use some already well-tested library for network access and are not coding that up yourself. If you do, your test(s) would of course have to cover that part the, too.)

Comment: The API is already covered with tests. These tests involve calling the api and testing that the correct response is received. I'd like to now test the flow within the web app and to test that the app behaves as expected for those browsers I wish to support. In other words, I'd like to treat the front-end as a subsystem and write sub system tests for it.

Answer (score 0):

For those who stumble upon this question, and do not want to end up writing the code to create their own mock server implementations of the API, you can use [Mocktastic](https://mocktastic.com/?ref=stackoverflow/41884606), which is a downloadable desktop application for Windows, MacOS and Linux, which provides an easy to use GUI to setup your mock API servers.