# Moq - Setup with constraint?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, moq

I'm trying to stub this:

```
public T GetCommand<T>() where T : ICommand, new()
```

I'm using Moq (C#), and my code looks like this:

```
_mockedBusinessFactory.Setup(x => x.GetCommand<ICommand>());
```

But there is a question: how to deal with the new() constraint?

Any idea?

Comment: I guess ICommand is an interface? If so you should mock out that interface and then `_mockedBusinessFactory.Setup(x => x.GetCommand<MockedOutICommand>());`

Comment: Can you finish the line, what do you want to set it up to do?

Comment: Also how would you use this, because `_factory.GetCommand<ICommand>()` isn't valid, as the `T` must be newable.

Comment: GetCommand is a method? Methods do not have new() constraint or am i missing something?

Comment: Yes, GetCommand is a method, and the ", new()" constraint mean that the provided T element must have a public ctor. Jamie, you wanna mock an interface? Do I miss something? I already try your syntax. 
@welton: this is classified code, I can't past more than that.

Comment: Do you not know what `T` is going to be when the mock is used? Or is that `T` not accessible from your scope? Related thread: [Mocking generic methods in Moq without specifying T](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072429/). Also: [Mocking generic method call for any given type parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311023/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
var stub = new Mock<ICommand>();
stub.Setup( //... setup stub

mockedBusinessFactory.Setup(x => x.GetCommand<ICommand>()).Returns(stub.Object);
```

PS. I'm not moq user