# Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times, with Func(T, TResult)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I appear to be having an issue with Mock.Verify that believes a method wasn't called but I can fully verify that it is.

**[Runnable version from Git](https://github.com/medmondson/Moq-Func-Issue)**

Unit test:

```
[Test]
public void IterateFiles_Called()
{
     Mock<IFileService> mock = new Mock<IFileService>();
     var flex = new Runner(mock.Object);

     List<ProcessOutput> outputs;
     mock.Verify(x => x.IterateFiles(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<string>>(),
                    It.IsAny<Func<string, ICsvConversionProcessParameter, ProcessOutput>>(),
                    It.IsAny<ICsvConversionProcessParameter>(),
                    It.IsAny<FileIterationErrorAction>(),
                    out outputs), Times.Once);

        }
```

**Alternative Unit test:** (after comment below)

```
[Test]
public void IterateFiles_Called()
{
     Mock<IFileService> mock = new Mock<IFileService>();
     var flex = new Runner(mock.Object);

     List<ProcessOutput> outputs;
     mock.Verify(x => x.IterateFiles(It.IsAny<string[]>(),
                        flex.ProcessFile, //Still fails
                        It.IsAny<ICsvConversionProcessParameter>(),
                        It.IsAny<FileIterationErrorAction>(),
                        out outputs), Times.Once);

}
```

Runner.cs:

```
public class Runner
    {
        public Runner(IFileService service)
        {
            string[] paths = new[] {"path1"};

            List<ProcessOutput> output = new List<ProcessOutput>();

            service.IterateFiles(paths, ProcessFile, new CsvParam(), FileIterationErrorAction.ContinueThenThrow, out output);
        }

        public ProcessOutput ProcessFile(string file, ICsvConversionProcessParameter parameters)
        {
            return new ProcessOutput();
        }
    }
```

When I debug I can see that `service.IterateFiles` is being called.  In addition as all parameters are marked with `It.IsAny<T>` the arguments passed don't matter (with the exception of the out parameter - my understand is this cannot be mocked).  Yet Moq disagrees the method is called.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: @NikolaiDante - Runnable version now available on Git https://github.com/medmondson/Moq-Func-Issue

Comment: You completely hide the fact that your method `void IterateFiles<TFileFunctionParameter, TFileFunctionOutput>(IEnumerable<string> filePaths,  
 Func<string, TFileFunctionParameter, TFileFunctionOutput> fileFunction,  
 TFileFunctionParameter fileFunctionParameter,  
 FileIterationErrorAction errorAction,  
 out List<TFileFunctionOutput> outputs);` is generic and requires two type parameters `TFileFunctionParameter` and `TFileFunctionOutput`. You should find out what types are substituted (inference) for `TFileFunctionParameter` and `TFileFunctionOutput` when you call the method in `Runner`.

Comment: ... (continued) Then you need to write your `It.IsAny<>()` expressions (inside the `Verify`) in a way that reproduces these inferred types. To find the values of `TFileFunctionParameter` and `TFileFunctionOutput` used inside `Runner`, it should be enough to "hover" the mouse over that method call in Visual Studio and read the types. If it is hard to read, check the generated IL. What version of the C# compiler and the .NET runtime (CLR) do you use?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - Thanks, you're spot on although unfortunately NikolaiDante (answer below) beat you to it.  Many thanks for taking the time to look though.

Comment: What I do not understand is that his answer modifies the type parameters inside the `runner` which might be OK, but we expect Moq to be able to mock this without changing the code in `runner`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - Good point I didn't quite think as far as that.  A bug in Moq?

Comment: Easy come, easy go. I guess I'll have to try harder today to claw back the 15 pts! ;-\

Comment: @NikolaiDante - Really sorry!  Your answer did solve my initial problem and many thanks for taking the time to pull the repo to look at it properly, but looking at Jeppe's answer I couldn't not mark that as answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NikolaiDante's answer together with the comments below it, essentially gives the explanation. Still, since I have investigated it a bit, I will try to write it clearly.

Your question entirely fails to show the main cause of your problem which is that the method is a *generic* one. We had to go to the Git files you link, to find out about that.

The method as declared in `IFileService` is:

```
void IterateFiles<TFileFunctionParameter, TFileFunctionOutput>(
    IEnumerable<string> filePaths,
    Func<string, TFileFunctionParameter, TFileFunctionOutput> fileFunction,
    TFileFunctionParameter fileFunctionParameter,
    FileIterationErrorAction errorAction,
    out List<TFileFunctionOutput> outputs);
```

To call it, one has to specify *both* the two type arguments, `TFileFunctionParameter` and `TFileFunctionOutput`, *and* the five ordinary arguments `filePaths`, `fileFunction`, `fileFunctionParameter`, `errorAction`, and  `outputs`.

C# is helpful and offers *type inference* with which we do not have to write the type arguments in the source code. The compiler figures which type arguments we want. But the two type arguments are still there, only "invisible". To see them, either hold your mouse over the generic method call below (and the Visual Studio IDE will show you them), or look at the output IL.

So inside your `Runner` class, the call really means:

```
service.IterateFiles<CsvParam, ProcessOutput>(paths,
  (Func<string, CsvParam, ProcessOutput>)ProcessFile,
  new CsvParam(), FileIterationErrorAction.ContinueThenThrow, out output);
```

Pay attention two the two types in the first line, and note that the method group `ProcessFile` is actually turned into a `Func<string, CsvParam, ProcessOutput>` even if the methods signature looks more like `Func<string, ICsvConversionProcessParameter, ProcessOutput>`. Delegates can be created from methods groups like that. (And it is not really relevant that `Func<in T1, in T2, out TResult>` is marked as contravariant in `T2`.)

If we inspect your `Verify`, then we see that type inference really sees it as:

```
mock.Verify(x => x.IterateFiles<ICsvConversionProcessParameter, ProcessOutput>(
  It.IsAny<IEnumerable<string>>(),
  It.IsAny<Func<string, ICsvConversionProcessParameter, ProcessOutput>>(),
  It.IsAny<ICsvConversionProcessParameter>(),
  It.IsAny<FileIterationErrorAction>(),
  out outputs), Times.Once);
```

So Moq cannot really verify that this is called, since the call uses a different first type argument, and also the `fileFunction` `Func<,,>` has another type. So this kind of explains you problem.

NikolaiDante shows how you can change `runner` to actually use the type arguments that your `Verify` expects.

But it feels more appropriate two change the *test* and keep the `runner` code unchanged. So what we want in the test, is:

```
mock.Verify(x => x.IterateFiles(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<string>>(),
  It.IsAny<Func<string, CsvParam, ProcessOutput>>(),
  It.IsAny<CsvParam>(),
  It.IsAny<FileIterationErrorAction>(),
  out outputs), Times.Once);
```

(type inference will give the correct `TFileFunctionParameter` and `TFileFunctionOutput` from this).

However: You have put your test class in another project/assembly than the `Runner` class. And the type `CsvParam` is `internal` to its assembly. So you really need to make `CsvParam` accessible to the test in my solution.

You can make `CsvParam` accessible either by making the class `public`, or by making the test assembly a "friend assembly" of the MoqIssue assembly by including the attribute:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MoqIssueTest")]
```

in some file belonging to the MoqIssue project.

Note that the Moq framework has no problems with an `internal` type, so you do not have to turn any of Moq's assemblies into "friends" for this. It is only required to express the `Verify` easily (i.e. without ugly reflection) in your MoqIssueTest assembly.

Comment: And see [Mocking generic method call for any given type parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311023/) for a vaguely related thread where it is clear that there is no "it-is-any" for type arguments.

Comment: Wow - excellent answer!  Thank you very much.  I've now marked this as answer since it more comprehensibly answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the problem is that something in the `Verify` doesn't exactly match what is there at run-time (it can be quite fickle).

I was able to get it pass via changing the code in `Runner` to:

```
service.IterateFiles<ICsvConversionProcessParameter, ProcessOutput>(paths, ProcessFile, new CsvParam(), FileIterationErrorAction.ContinueThenThrow, out output);
```

(Specifiying `TFileFunctionParameter` and `TFileFunctionOutput` explicitly)

Which seemed to help nail down the types for moq's verify to match.

As @Lukazoid said much better than I," Moq treats DoSomething as a different method to DoSomething."

---

Some candidates, since ruled out:

- There seems to be a mismatch between `Func<string, ICsvConversionProcessParameter, ProcessOutput>` and `ProcessFile` as `ProcessFile` doesn't seem to be defined as a func.
- Another potential difference I can see is `string[]` vs `IEnumerable<string>`.
- `List<ProcessOutput>` as the out param

Comment: `Process file` is assignable to `Func<string,  CsvConversionProcessParameter, ProcessOutput>` therefore am I not correct in believing `Is.IsAny<Func<string, ICsvConversionProcessParameter, ProcessOutput` should match?

Comment: I'm not sure if assignable is enough for it to be a match. If you temporarily make it public and change the verify does the test pass then?

Comment: I've made it public (to no avail), how do you suggest changing the verify?

Comment: You pass ProcessFile in the method were testing,  so do the same in the verify?

Comment: I've updated my question above with your suggestion, hasn't made any different unfortunately.

Comment: Added string[] in too - no difference.  Will attempt to get a runnable version online.

Comment: Basically, your problem is that something in the verify doesn't exactly match what is there at run-time (it can be quite fickle), sorry i haven't been more help and have been shooting in the dark. :-\

Comment: @Lukazoid my assumption was that by specifiying the generic parameters, it stopped verify misinterpretting it to some wierd thing from within the mock?

Comment: Seems to work - assume it's to do with Moq 'guessing' types wrong.  Thanks