# moq generic method setup on interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

How does one setup a generic method using moq library in C#? Such as

```
Interface IA
{
    void foo();
    void Get<T>();
}

[Fact]
public void SetupGenericMethod()
{
    var mock = new Mock<IA>();
    mock.Setup(x=> x.Get<It.IsAny<???>()>()
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking generic methods in Moq without specifying T](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072429/mocking-generic-methods-in-moq-without-specifying-t)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to do something that related to the type `T`, It can be done since Moq 4.13 (2019-09-01) by using `It.IsAnyType` for generic type arguments:

```
mock.Setup(x => x.Get<It.IsAnyType>())
```

Full Example:

```
public interface IA
{
    void Get<T>();
}


[Fact]
public void test()
{
    // Arrange
    bool didCallBackCalled = false;
    var mock = new Mock<IA>();
    mock.Setup(x => x.Get<It.IsAnyType>()).Callback(() => didCallBackCalled = true);

    // Act
    mock.Object.Get<string>();

    // Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(didCallBackCalled);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When testing you should know what `T` should be for the test. Use the type for the setup. Also based on the naming in your example `Get<T>` should be returning something.

```
Interface IA
{
    void foo();
    T Get<T>();
}

[Fact]
public void SetupGenericMethod()
{
    var mockT = new Mock<FakeType>(); 
    var mock = new Mock<IA>();
    mock.Setup(x=> x.Get<FakeType>()).Returns(mockT.Object);
}
```

If you are actually looking for [Mocking generic method call for any given type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5311508/5233410). Then the answer to that question was to forego creating a mock and instead use a [Stub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346372/whats-the-difference-between-faking-mocking-and-stubbing/346440#346440), or mocking the interface yourself instead of using a mocking framework.