# Moq can not mock a method without specific generic type

Tags: c#, generics, testing, mocking

I have a test that find all class that inherited from `BaseClass`. `BaseClass`  has a property with a method that use generics:

```
abstract class BaseClass 
{
   public MyTools Tools { get; set;}

   public abstract List<TEntity> GetAll();

   public virtual IList<TEntity> Convert<TEntity, TEntityOther>() 
   {
       //...
   }
}

class MyTools 
{
   IList<T> List<T>();    
}
```

Then, I need to mock the `T List<T>()` method. The method is used in `Create` method. For example:

```
class MyClass: BaseClass<MyEntity>
{
    public override List<MyEntity> GetAll()
    {
        var x = this.MyTools.List<SomeClass>();

        return this.Convert<MyEntity, SomeClass>(x);
    }
}
```

I don't know what type is used within `GetAll` to call `List` method.

This is my test:

```
var xobjects = this.GetTypeInNamespace(myAssembly, typeof(BaseClass<>));

foreach(var obj in xobjects) 
{
   var myTools  = new Mock<MyTools>();

   //here is my problem
   myTools.Setup(x => x.List< ANY >()).Returns(new List< ANY >());

   var iobj = this.CreateInstance(obj);

   iobj.MyTools = myTools.Object;  

   var result = iobj.GetType().GetMethod("GetAll").Invoke(iobj, null);

   ((ICollection)result).Count.Should().Be(0);
}
```

How I can setup the method `List <T>` for any T?

I don't know what type is `T` and I do not care what type it is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @Nkosi ready, I added more details

Comment: this example method is still confusing `this.Convert<MyEntity, SomeClass>(x);`

Comment: `List<T>()` returns an instance of `T` or a an instance of `List<T>`? The naming is confusing when compared to what it is suppose to return.

Comment: @Nkosi yes, you are right. I fixed it. `List<T>` return a list of `T`. The application is big, I extracted a part of that. That was my mistake

Comment: There are too many inconsistencies in this question which only leads to guessing what the problem is. Provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Related to [Mocking generic method call for any given type parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311023/).

Comment: Is `MyTools` a class (as shown) or an interface? If it is a class, the declaration of the generic method you are trying to mock is not precise enough. Is it a `virtual` method?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen MyTools is a interface in my real project. The method `List<T>` is not virtual, and I need mock for any type.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen in the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311023/mocking-generic-method-call-for-any-given-type-parameter they know the type, in the explame is `ATable`, but I don't know the type and I don't matter the type

Comment: Does the interface `MyTools` contain many other members, besides the generic method in question, in the "real project"? Because if this is hard to do with Moq, maybe it is easy to just write a dummy class that implements the interface, and inject that, instead of using Moq.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen yes, it is a good solution, I'm working with that, the problem is that I have 30+ method in `MyTools` interface

Comment: This is not really supported by Moq. You can change to `var myTools  = new Mock<MyTools> { DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock, };` and not make any Setup on the method in question. Then the loose mock will create a "recursive" mock when the method is invoked. This will be a proxy class that inherits from `List<WhateverTypeArg>`. This is possible because `List<>` is not sealed and has an accessible zero-parameter constructor. This "next-level" mock will act just like an empty `List<>`. Note: There are no `virtual` methods/properties on `List<>`, so Moq's deriving class will be just like `List<>`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen finally, I implemented your propose "maybe it is easy to just write a dummy class that ...". Can you add an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm aware the question is 3 years old, but since [moq 4.13](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#matching-generic-type-arguments-moq-413) it is possible to specify `It.IsAnyType` for generic type matching.