# Net Core: Moq Method with Generic Class T and Parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq

I am trying to Moq this method below. How would I moq a method with a Generic Class T? Below is method and currently attemping solution,

**Method:**

```
    public async Task<TV> HttpPost<T, TV>(string url, T prm, string accessToken = null)
    {
        try
        {
            if ((accessToken ?? "").Length > 0)
                _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            using (var result = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, prm))
            {
                result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                using (var content = result.Content)
                {
                    var ret = await content.ReadAsJsonAsync<TV>();
                    return ret;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var message = $"Url: {url}, Data: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(prm)}";
            ex.Data["Url"] = message;
            throw;
        }
    }
```

**Attempt:**

```
        var mock = new Mock<HttpDataLayerUtilsAsync>();
        mock.Setup(b => b.HttpPost(It.IsAny<string>, It.IsAny <CustomDataModelRequest>).Returns..
```

Resource:

[Mocking generic method call for any given type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311023/mocking-generic-method-call-for-any-given-type-parameter)

Comment: Specify the type arguments explicitly, i.e. `mock.Setup(b => b.HttpPost<CustomDataModelRequest, CustomDataModelResponse>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny <CustomDataModelRequest>(), null)).ReturnsAsync(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply the generic arguments to the `HttpPost` in the Setup, for example:

```
//                           T                         TV
.Setup(b => b.HttpPost<CustomDataModelRequest, CustomDataModelResponse>(
  It.IsAny<string>(), 
  It.IsAny<CustomDataModelRequest>(), 
  null))
```

As well as passing a value for the optional parameter.

For the `Return` you can use:

```
.ReturnsAsync(new CustomDataModelResponse());
```

Then you can call it like so:

```
var result = await mock.Object.HttpPost<CustomDataModelRequest, CustomDataModelResponse>("", new CustomDataModelRequest(), "");
```