# Testing software: fake vs stub

Tags: testing, terminology, stub

There are quite a few written about stub vs mocks, but I can't see the real difference between fake and stub. Can anyone put some light on it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between faking, mocking, and stubbing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346372/whats-the-difference-between-faking-mocking-and-stubbing)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the terminology as introduced by Meszaros. Martin Fowler does also [mentions them](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) regularly. I think he explains the difference pretty well in that article.

Nevertheless, I'll try again in my own words :)

A Fake is closer to a real-world implementation than a stub. Stubs contain basically hard-coded responses to an expected request; they are commonly used in unit tests, but they are incapable of handling input other than what was pre-programmed.

Fakes have a more real implementation, like some kind of state that may be kept for example. They can be useful for system tests as well as for unit testing purposes, but they aren't intended for production use because of some limitation or quality requirement.

Answer (score 36):

A **fake** has the same behavior as the thing that it replaces.

A **stub** has a "fixed" set of "canned" responses that are specific to your test(s).

A **mock** has a set of expectations about calls that are made. If these expectations are not met, the test fails.

All of these are similar in that they replace production collaborators that code under test uses.

Comment: the term "keep it simple" does not apply here. I mean, if you can't find a simple, concrete example to explain differences, then it's just phrasing. IMO All these definitions are the same unless we can demonstrate it it with a simple example. I mean, far from help people, this confuses people a lot.

Answer (score 6):

To paraphrase Roy Osherove in his book The Art of Unit Testing (second edition):

A **Fake** is any object made to imitate another object.  Fakes can be *used* either as stubs or mocks.

A **Stub** is a fake that is provided to the class you are testing to satisfy its requirements, but is otherwise ignored in the unit test.

A **Mock** is a fake that is provided to the class you are testing, *and* will be inspected as part of the unit test to verify functionality.

For example, the `MyClass` class you are testing may utilize both a local logger and a third-party web service as part of its operation.  You would create a `FakeLogger` and a `FakeWebService`, but how they are used determines whether they are stubs or mocks.

The `FakeLogger` might be used as a **stub**: it is provided to `MyClass` and pretends to be a logger, but actually ignores all input and is otherwise just there to get `MyClass` to operate normally.  You don't actually check `FakeLogger` in your unit tests, and as far as you're concerned it's there to make the compiler shut up.

The `FakeWebService` might be used as a **mock**: you provide it to `MyClass`, and in one of your units tests you call `MyClass.Foo()` which is supposed to call the third party web service.  To verify that this happened, you now check your `FakeWebService` to see if it recorded the call that it was supposed to receive.

Note that either of these could be reversed and depend on what it is you're testing in a particular unit test. If your unit test is testing the content of what is being logged then you could make a `FakeLogger` that dutifully records everything it's told so you can interrogate it during the unit test; this is now a mock.  In the same test you might not care about when the third-party web service is called; your `FakeWebService` is now a stub.  How you fill in the functions of your fake thus depends on whether it needs to be used as a stub or a mock or both.

In summary (direct quote from the book):

> A *fake* is a generic term that can be used to describe either a stub or a mock object because they both look like the real object. . . . The basic difference is that stubs can't fail tests.  Mocks can.

All the rest is implementation details.

Comment: While I personally think this definition of stub makes more sense, it seems to me that isn't consistent with the definition used by many others (which maybe all come from Martin Fowler). =/

Answer (score 5):

These might help

- http://xunitpatterns.com/Mocks,%20Fakes,%20Stubs%20and%20Dummies.html
- http://hamletdarcy.blogspot.com/2007/10/mocks-and-stubs-arent-spies.html

Comment: That first link shows just how complex this topic is, and how no two people seem to share the same definitions.  As an example the answer to the StackOverflow question [What's the difference between faking, mocking, and stubbing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346372/whats-the-difference-between-faking-mocking-and-stubbing) seems to reverse the definitions of Stub and Fake compared to Thorarin's answer to this question.

Comment: Sorry to nitpick, but it's best practice to summarize relevant parts of links in case they go dead.  An answer should be more than links.