# Unit Test Entity Framework Data Annotations

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Currently, I've written a repository in which entities are being stored. 
That entity is an object and is inheriting from the base class "Entity".

```
public class Entity
{
    #region Constructors

    public Entity() : this(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now) { }

    public Entity(DateTime creationDate, DateTime updateDate)
    {
        DateCreated = creationDate;
        DateUpdated = updateDate;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    [Key]
    [Required]
    [Column(Order= 0)]
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(Order = 998)]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; private set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(Order = 999)]
    public DateTime DateUpdated { get; internal set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Now I want to unit test (not integration test) the repository holding an object that implements an Entity.

I've created a fake repository that uses a HashSet to store objects in memory.
Now, the problem is that, when I add entities to my repository, all the Id values are assigned '0' which is normal.

On Entity Framework, they are assigned a unique int value (starting from 0), which is also normal due to the data annotations.

Now I would like to know how I can mimic the same behaviour for the Data Annotations when running unit tests, because right now, I can have multiple records in my repository which the same 'Key' value, which should off course not be possible under any circumstances.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already using constructor chaining to pass in default `DateTime` values for `creationDate` and `updateDate` -- why not add one more?

```
public class Entity
{
    #region Constructors

    public Entity() : this(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, default(int)) { }

    public Entity(DateTime creationDate, DateTime updateDate, int id)
    {
        DateCreated = creationDate;
        DateUpdated = updateDate;
        Id = id
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    [Key]
    [Required]
    [Column(Order= 0)]
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(Order = 998)]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; private set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(Order = 999)]
    public DateTime DateUpdated { get; internal set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Then you can generate a unique ID for each entity as necessary.

Comment: I've thought about that to be honest. But I just wanted to check if there were other ways to test it. Maybe those attributes have some hidden magic power in them...

Comment: That's one of the reasons I don't like EF, TBQH. It encourages you to dirty your beautiful, pristine POCOs with a bunch of EF attributes.

Comment: @DanielMann One does not have to since there is the fluent api: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to test the wrong thing. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? `KeyAttribute` is an implementation detail of your storage layer, and you don't want to test that -- it's the vendor's job to ensure it works.

A fake repository is a means of testing something else that depends on the repository interface in isolation. Thus, what you probably should be doing is creating a test case wherein your repository is set up to throw an exception appropriate for a duplicate key scenario, then verifying that your system under test does the right thing when it encounters that exception.

However, you may wish to ensure that all your entities have `KeyAttribute` on their Id property. You can do that as a single unit test that enumerates your entity types and uses reflection to verify the existence of the attribute.

Comment: My repository holds a collection of objects and has a method GetById which I would like to test. Therfore all entities should have different id's.

Comment: Help me understand: under which circumstances does it make sense for you to be testing an implementation of a method of a *fake* class?

Comment: There you have a point. But I'd like to achieve almost 100% code coverage so therefore it's needed to test. It might not be needed but I like those numbers. And I might  have a class that takes an implementation of a repository. So to unit test it I need to pass an implementation of it which is a fake. Makes that more sense?

Comment: Code coverage is a meaningless metric. It doesn't prove anything about the quality of your code or the number of bugs present. It's more important to test the right things.

Comment: I know, but I think I'm just fanisacted by those numbers.

Comment: For the cases where you have a SUT that depends on the repository interface, pass in either a mock or a fake that is tailored for that specific test case.

Comment: If you do that, you don't have to test the test-fake, because it will be as dumb as it gets -- yet you can still get 100% coverage.

Comment: And what exactely is the difference between a mock and a fake from a technical point of view?

Comment: Mocks tend to be dynamically generated code where you can declaratively specify behavior on a case-by-case basis to the tune of "when the repository method Add() is called with any object, throw a duplicate key exception". I tend to prefer mocks, and when I don't use mocks, I write stubs. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808070/testing-software-fake-vs-stub for a discussion about the different terms. :)

Comment: I just want to second what @Rytmis is saying. Seems pointless to test a fake repository. Makes sense to test a service/controller/something using a fake repository. If you wanted to test your repository, you would want to mock your data context. I usually wouldn't go that far. Roy Osherove's The Art of Unit Testing is a good read also.