# Do I need to explicitly set expected return values on Mock object only?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

Is my observation correct:

```
public intercafe IMyInterface { bool IsOK {get;set;} }

// If I use stub this always return true:
var stub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IMyInterface>();
stub.IsOK = true;

// But if I use MOCK this always return false -NOT True
var mock= MockRepository.GenerateMock<IMyInterface>();
mock.IsOK = true;
```

If I am right; why is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can set `mock.IsOK` to return true by setting an expectation on it and providing a return value:

```
var mock= MockRepository.GenerateMock<IMyInterface>();
mock.Expect(x => x.IsOK).Return(true);
```

Of course, to understand why, it helps to understand the difference between mocks and stubs. Martin Fowler does a better job in [this article](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) than I could.

Basically, a stub is intended to be used to provide dummy values, and in that sense Rhino.Mocks allows you to very easily arrange what you want those dummy values to be:

```
stub.IsOK = true;
```

Mocks, on the other hand, are intended to help you test behavior by allowing you to set expectation on a method. In this case Rhino.Mocks allows you to arrange your expectations using the following syntax:

```
mock.Expect(x => x.IsOK).Return(true);
```

Because a Mock and a Stub serve two different purposes they have entirely different implementations.

In the case of your Mock example:

```
var mock= MockRepository.GenerateMock<IMyInterface>();
mock.IsOK = true;
```

I wouldn't be surprised if the implementation of the `IsOK` setter on your mock is empty or ignoring your call completely.

Answer (score 0):

You've not specified for the mock that it should store the value and return that value, so it's just returning the default value of a `bool`. I'd say the reason for the difference in behaviour is because there is an implied difference between mocks and stubs in terms of usage, intent and behaviour.

Have a bit of a read-up on the differences between mocks, stubs and fakes. Not *everyone* agrees on a single answer, but you'll see there's a general consensus. Starting here might help: [What's the difference between faking, mocking, and stubbing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346372/whats-the-difference-between-faking-mocking-and-stubbing)