# What is the difference between mocks, stubs and fake objects

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, stub

Although there are plenty of resources, even here on SO, only two of the terms are compared to each other in these Q/A.

So, in short, what is each one of them? And how they all relate to each other? Or don't they at all?

Comment: This would probably be better posed on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html

Comment: And http://xunitpatterns.com/Mocks,%20Fakes,%20Stubs%20and%20Dummies.html

Comment: @BedwyrHumphreys Thanks for the fowler link. This is it, because later on he also talks about fakes, besides the two mentioned in the tile. Please add that as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between faking, mocking, and stubbing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346372/whats-the-difference-between-faking-mocking-and-stubbing)

Comment: Ironically, my question has already been answered by this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/346372/79485

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Difference between mock and stub is very simple - **mock can make your test fail, while stub can't**. That's all there is. Additionally, you can think of stub as of something that *provides values*. Nowadays, fake is just a generic term for both of them (more on that later).

### Example

Let's consider a case where you have to build a service that sends packages via communication protocol (exact details are irrelevant). You simply supply service with package code and it does the rest. Given the snippet below, can you identify which dependency would be a stub and which mock in potential unit test?

```
public class DistributionService
{
    public double SendPackage(string packageCode)
    {
        var contents = this.packageService.GetPackageContents(packageCode);
        if (contents == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "Attempt to send non-exisiting package");
        }

        var package = this.packageBuilder.Build(contents);
        this.packageDistributor.Send(package);
    }
}
```

It's fairly easy to tell that `packageBuilder` simply provides value and there's no possible way it could make any test fail. That's a **stub**. Even though it might seem more blurry, `packageService` is stub too. It provides a value (what we do with the value is irrelevant from stub's point of view). Of course, later we'll use that value to test whether exception is thrown, but it's still all within our control (as in, we tell stub exactly what to do and forget about it - it should have no further influence on test).

It gets different with `packageDistributor`. Even if it provides any value, it's not consumed. Yet the call to `Send` seems to be pretty important part of our implementation and we'll most likely want to **verify** it is called.

At this point we should get to a conclusion that `packageDistributor` is a **mock**. We'll have a dedicated unit test asserting that `Send` method was called and if for some reasons it wasn't - we want to know that, as it's **important part of the entire process**. Other dependencies are stubs as all they do is provide values to other, perhaps more relevant pieces of code.

### Quick glance at TDD

Stub being stub, could be just as well replaced with constant value in *naive implementation*:

```
var contents = "Important package";
var package = "<package>Important package</package>";
this.packageDistributor.Send(package);
```

This is essentially what mocking frameworks do with stubs - instruct them to return configurable/explicit value. *Old-school, hand-rolled* stubs often do just that - return constant value.

Obviously, such code doesn't make much sense, but anyone who ever done TDD surely seen bunch of such *naive implementations* at the early stage of class development. Iterative development that results from TDD will often help **identify roles** of your class' dependencies.

### Stubs, mocks and fakes nowadays

At the beginning of this post I mentioned that *fake* is just a generic term. Given that mock can also serve as stub (especially when modern mocking frameworks are concerned), to avoid confusion it's good idea to call such object a fake. Nowadays, you can see this trend growing - original *mock - stub* distinction is slowly becoming a thing of the past and more universal names are used. For example:

- FakeItEasy uses *fake*
- NSubstitute uses *substitute*
- Moq uses *mock* (name is old, but no visible distinction is made whether it's stub or mock)

### References, further reading

- **[Mocks aren't stubs](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html)** by Martin Fowler - you can see this article being linked virtually under any stub/mock question, and it's for a reason
- **[Exploring The Continuum Of Test Doubles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163358.aspx)** by Mark Seemann - overview for all the confusing unit testing terminology (if you thought mock, fake and stub are enough, you probably should know there's also *dummy**, *spy*, *double* and what not)
- **[xunitpatterns.com](http://www.xunitpatterns.com)** - backing-website for huge unit-testing-patterns book, [xUnit Test Patterns: Refactoring Test Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131495054) by Gerard Meszaros
- **[Art of Unit Testing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988274)** by Roy Osherove - excellent unit testing introductory book (the *"mock can make test fail, stub not"* are Roy's words, not mine)

Comment: Thank you for this thorough answer. I especially like the first sentence which brings it to the point, and that you mention that nowadays it all somewhat blurs into just "fake".

Answer (score 6):

Mock and Stub are both called Fake Object. In my opinion:

- Stub is used to replace the external dependency, it make our tests run without exceptions. We must use Assert to determine the test fail or not. Stub is only suitable for testing the result of some functions are correct or not
- Mock is more complex, often used to test behaviors, e.g. verifying is a function called or not

Answer (score 2):

They are generally interchangeable but there are slight differences in my opinion.

- A mock/fake object will return realistic looking results.
- A stub will return a default fail/pass value.