# Should I mock local method invocation inside a tested method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, stubbing

My question about the concept of unit testing:

```
class A {
   public void m1() {
      // code
      m2();
      //code
   }

   public void m2() {
      //some code
   }

}
```

According to best practices, how should I test the `m1` method? Is the unit the class or is the unit the method?

My view - I should test `m2` separately and I shouldn't test `m1` and `m2` integration.

To use my view is hard enough - I should use sophisticated frameworks for testing and use very modern things.

According to my sense of unit testing, tests should be simple! If your code is good, you can test it without sophisticated things. But invoking m2() inside m1() is normal code.

Please clarify my misunderstanding.

### update:

**mocking example(pseudocode):**

```
//prepare
A testClass = mock(A.class);
when(testClass.m2()).doNothing();
when(testClass.m1()).callRealMethod();
//execute:
testClass.m1();
//verify
check testClass state after method m1 invocation.
```

This is how I test a mocked class. Is this normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, when you unit-test, test all public methods. In your example `m1` and `m2` are public, so you'd have tests for both.

There are several reasons that you might want to stub or mock `m2`:

1. If, when you test `m1`, you encounter any problems because `m1` calls `m2`, stub or mock `m2`. Some problems you might encounter:

   - `m2` might call external services
   - `m2` might just be slow
   - it might be difficult to call `m1` with parameters that satisfy `m2` (your `m2` has no parameters, but I'm speaking generally)
2. Sometimes, when you test a method that calls another method and also test the other method, you find that there is duplication between the tests of the two methods -- some of the tests of the calling method are really testing the called method. Deal with that by stubbing or mocking the called method out of the calling method, testing the calling method just enough to prove that the called method is called, and thoroughly testing the called method.
3. If you do TDD, you might write `m1` before you write `m2`. You would then stub or mock `m2` so that your tests of `m1` would pass, and then go on to test and write `m2`.

But if you don't have any reason to stub or mock `m2`, don't. It is common and reasonable for a method to call other methods in ways that don't require stubbing or mocking. The called methods might be short and simple, or the calling method might just be broken up into a bunch of subsidiary methods for readability. That's even true if the called method is in another class (because it's used by more than one calling method); if it is fully tested by tests of methods that call it, and if there is no duplication between tests, there is no need to stub or mock.

The example above of mocking `m2` without running `m1` is a perfectly normal thing to want to do and it gets the job done, but it's ugly since Mockito takes over all of a class's methods. You can do it more nicely with a Mockito spy, discussed here: [What is the difference between mocking and spying when using Mockito?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052984/mockito-mock-vs-spy).

```
A a = spy(new A());
doNothing().when(spy).m2();
a.m1();
# check state of a
```

Comment: To mock m2 method - I should to mock object. Hence I forced to test method invokation of mocked object(I am about m1 method). Is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

You should still test m1().

You could use mocks of method m2(),

Comment: At this case I should mock A and after test mock.

Answer (score 0):

The origin a the term *unit test* is from "unit of work". A distinct *unit of work* is often, but not always a single method. In practice unit test often refers to testing a single class (compare [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)) and contrasts integration and acceptance tests. The JUnit framework comes from unit testing, but nowadays is used for all kinds and layers of tests.

As a basic rule of thumb you should test all public methods. If you want, include negative tests, which feed your methods with invalid input. Usually they reveal the code's weaknesses. If two public methods overlap - as in your case - I am not aware of a hard use-all-the-time principle. You could

- A) Use [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) or similar to mock m2() during access from m1().
- B) Test m1() and m2() the ususal way.

A) gives you a test more sensitive to m1 code but is more costly. Choose this if m1 code is important as a single unit of work. B) is the faster result and in my opinion is the better option as in case of an m1 error you will see immediately if there is an error in m2 as well. Maybe leave a small nice comment for other programmers that explains the dependence.

Comment: At this case I should mock A class, say doNothing for m2 and then say call realMethod for m1. Usually I tested only real object with injected mock objects. Is it normally to test mock ?

Comment: It is more common to mock whole classes, not methods. As I said, you have to decide if in this special case it is *worth* to you to have a special m1-only test.

Comment: I am about test method for m1

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last question. Test *every* public method. That is, m1 and m2. In m1 you can either mock m2 oder leave it as it is. The details I explained in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Consider for a moment that `m1` was *not* dependent on `m2`.

Now consider that `m1` didn't invoke `m2`, but rather duplicated the code of `m2` within itself.

(In either of the above scenarios, you would test both `m1` and `m2`, right?)

Now consider what would happen if you refactored `m1` to remove duplicate code, by having it invoke `m2`. Since this is a true refactoring (i.e., it does not change the behavior of the method), your existing tests should continue to pass.

My point is that the dependence of `m1` on `m2` is a private implementation detail. You generally want to hide implementation details from your tests, in order to keep them from becoming brittle. Consequently, you should write your tests as if they had no idea about this dependency.

**Edit:** Adding some code to demonstrate.

Imagine we had written the following code and tests (apologies for any syntax errors; I don't have a compiler handy):

```
interface Foo {
    public void doStuff(int value);
}

interface Bar {
    public void doOtherStuff();
}

class MyClass {
    private Foo foo;
    private Bar bar;

    public MyClass(Foo foo, Bar bar) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public void m1() {
        foo.doStuff(42);
        foo.doOtherStuff();
    }

    public void m2() {
        foo.doStuff(42);
    }
}

@Test
public void m1ShouldDoALotOfStuff() throws Exception {
    Foo foo = PowerMockito.mock(Foo.class);
    Bar bar = PowerMockito.mock(Bar.class);
    MyClass sut = new MyClass(foo, bar);

    sut.m1();

    verify(foo).doStuff(42);
    verify(bar).doOtherStuff();
}

@Test
public void m2ShouldJustDoStuff() throws Exception {
    Foo foo = PowerMockito.mock(Foo.class);
    Bar bar = PowerMockito.mock(Bar.class);
    MyClass sut = new MyClass(foo, bar);

    sut.m2();

    verify(foo).doStuff(42);
}
```

In the above code we have green tests for both `m1` and `m2`. Now we notice that there is some duplicated code in `m1` and `m2`: `foo.doStuff(42);`. So we refactor `m1` to get rid of the duplication:

```
    public void m1() {
        m2();
        foo.doOtherStuff();
    }
```

Our tests are still green after making this change, because we haven't changed the behavior of `m1`; we've only changed the *details* of how it carries out that behavior. In order to be robust, our tests should test **what** we expect the SUT to do without testing **how** it does it.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include some code to demonstrate what I'm talking about. (Note that I only mock external dependencies; not internal ones.)