# How to mock a method call inside another method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Here is my code:

```
`public class Service {
   callSomeService(ContextTpye1 c1,Parameter p){
   //do something here
   ContextTpye2 c2 = constructContext(c1,p);      
   if(c2.timeout()){
      c2.audit();
     }
   }
 }`
```

In the unit test, the Service, Parameter and ContextTpye1 are initialized. Is it possible to only mock c2.audit()? I wanna it to doNothing here. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I mock local method invocation inside a tested method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653583/should-i-mock-local-method-invocation-inside-a-tested-method)

Comment: They are different! Here another class was created and I only want a partial mock. Please read my question.

Answer (score 1):

So the way I would attack the problem assuming `constructContext(c1,p)` is `public` is to when testing the `Service` class is to spy on the `Service` allowing you to mock the `constructContext(c1,p)` and returning a mock of `ContextType2`.

```
public class ServiceTest
{
    private Service service = Mockito.spy(new Service());

    private ContextType2 c2 = Mockito.mock(ContextType2.class);

    @Test
    public void testCallSomeService()
    {
        Mockito.when(service.constructContext(Mockito.eq(ContextType1.class), Mockito.eq(Parameter.class))).thenReturn(c2);
            Mockito.when(c2.timeout()).thenReturn(true);
        Mockito.when(c2.audit()).doNothing();
            service.callSomeService(new ContextType1(), new Parameter());
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot just do 'Mockito.when(c2.timeout()).thenReturn(true);' There are some calculation in c2 to give this value.

Comment: What's the point then? Why are you testing ContextType2.timeout() in the service test case? If you want to test the timeout method create a test cases for the ContextType2 class. In the Service class test cases you should be testing service class methods, not the methods of other classes that the service class calls.