# Use static initialization block with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I am starting up with Mockito as my mocking framemork. I try to mock some custom class with it:

```
//usage
@Mock
private LoginAttempt loginAttempt;
```

and the `LoginAttempt` class:

```
public class LoginAttempt {
    private static LoginAttempt loginAttempt;

    static {
        loginAttempt = new LoginAttempt();
        loginAttempt.setOs(TEST_GLOBALS.OS);
        loginAttempt.setBrowser(TEST_GLOBALS.BROWSER);
        loginAttempt.setDevice(TEST_GLOBALS.DEVICE);
        loginAttempt.setOsVersion(TEST_GLOBALS.OS_VERSION);
        loginAttempt.setBrowserVersion(TEST_GLOBALS.BROWSER_VERSION);
    }
...
```

But when I debug my test cases, the `loginAttempt` var is empty. What am I doing wrong?

I saw in tutorials, that I should do something like this:

```
private static LoginAttempt loginAttempt = new LoginAttempt();
```

But what if I want to preinitialize some field values?

**EDIT** my `loginAttempt` is not null, but the values I assigned in the static block are not initialized.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be anything to do with Mockito.  What happens if you check the value of `LoginAttempt.loginAttempt.os` in any one of your methods?

Comment: What is `TEST_GLOBALS`? It's spelled like a constant but not used like one.

Comment: @LewBloch its a class containing constants.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I try it today after job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's good to know the difference between Mock and Spy, the real reason is in the edit below.  Otherwise see [What is the difference between mocking and spying when using Mockito?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052984/what-is-the-difference-between-mocking-and-spying-when-using-mockito) for more info about the difference.

EDIT:  I noticed you are missing the annotation to enable mockito on a class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LoginAttemptTest {
    @Mock
    LoginAttempt loginAttempt;

    @Test
    public void testObjectExistence() {
        System.out.println("loginAttempt="+loginAttempt);
    }
}
```

Comment: I try it, seams it is what I am looking for. I accept the answer as soon as I have check it.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem You are right, he was missing the annotation RunWith to enable mockito annotations.