# How to cover static fields with unit tests using mock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, static, mockito

```
public class CacheAdder{

private static final int HARD_CACHE;

static {
    HARD_CACHE = 22;
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  public int divide(int number, int divider) {
         return  (int) HARD_CACHE+number/divider;
    }
}
```

When I mock and run tests through this example class, mockito skips the static part which makes sense because I mock the value of HARD_CACHE but at the same time I want 100% coverage through the code. Should static fields be tested without mocks? Or is there a way to test static fields/methods/variables using mocks?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use reflection for setting the value to the static field

You can look here: [Mock private static final field using mockito or Jmockit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30703149/mock-private-static-final-field-using-mockito-or-jmockit)

Comment: Yes but I'm asking about a field, this is a class called Logger which can be mocked without any problem. In other words what I'm asking is mocking HARD_CACHE but also waiting 3 seconds

Comment: Check how you initialize mocks, otherwise, try to use spy instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577079/use-static-initialization-block-with-mockito