# MockedObject and Real Object give different results

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I have started learning JUNIT.
Here is what i am trying to achieve.
I have a class which checks if the inputString is part of secretKey;

```
public class StringChecker {


public boolean isEqual(String name)
{
    boolean isEqual = false;
    if(getSecretKey().contains(name))
    {
        isEqual = true;
    }

    return isEqual;
}

public String getSecretKey()
{
    return "OSKAR";
}

}
```

> My test class is this

```
public class RandomCheck {

@Test
public void isEqualTest()
{
    StringChecker stringChecker = mock(StringChecker.class);

    when(stringChecker.getSecretKey()).thenReturn("james");

    //assertEquals(true, new StringChecker().isEqual("OSKAR"));     <----this test case passes

    assertEquals(true, stringChecker.isEqual("james"));

}

}
```

When i use Mocked object it does not give me the expected result, hence failing the test. But when i use a real object it gives me expected result and passes the test.
Am i missing anything? Like any annotation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mockito mock is an object having the interface of the mocked class, but not its implementation. Your `StringChecker` is mocked, meaning there is no implementation code making calls from `isEqual` to `getSecretKey` as you assume.

You could use mockito `spy`, See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052984/what-is-the-difference-between-mocking-and-spying-when-using-mockito):

> **Mockito.spy()** is a recommended way of creating partial mocks. The reason is it guarantees real methods are called against correctly constructed object because you're responsible for constructing the object passed to spy() method.

Comment: i did not understand . Are you asking or telling the solution ?

Comment: Its an answer. Once you mocked the class, it is not the real thing (object) anymore. So the implementation code inside `StringChecker` is not as well. You set a mocked return value on `getSecretKey`, but not on `isEqual`.

Comment: If you would like to test like in your example you could use mockito `spy`, where you selectively mock only part of a class and keep the remainder 'real'.

Comment: i was assuming since i have used when().then return . it will give me the String value when it will be called inside mocked class . Am i wrong here ?

Comment: Yes, that works, but `stringChecker.isEqual()` has no implementation code in the mock, so calling it without setting it makes no sense (and in this case setting it, then testing it makes no sense at well :)

Comment: How can i do that can you please add in your answer ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151178/discussion-between-arnold-schrijver-and-rohit-singh).

Comment: PS If this is real code and security is important, don't store your secret key like this..

Answer (score 1):

**ROOKIE MISTAKE**

Here's the **rookie** mistake i did (mentioned by [Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8295283/arnold-schrijver)).
I mocked the StringChecker class but **i did not provide any implementation** **for** **isEqual(String) method**.
 And because there was no implementation, i was getting the default value. In this case **false** (return type of method is boolean).

> Solution

Using static method spy(). (Again mentioned by @Arnold).
So here is what my working code looks like.

```
@Test
public void isEqualTest()
{
    StringChecker stringChecker = new StringChecker();

    StringChecker spy = spy(stringChecker);

    when(spy.getSecretKey()).thenReturn("james");  // providing implementation for the method

    assertEquals(true, spy.isEqual("james"));

}
```

> What i learnt from it.

Just by mocking an object does not get your things done if you intend to use methods of mocked object (In simple terms **PROVIDE IMPLEMENTATION** for methods of mocked objects).

> TIP

If you want to see the default value returned by mocked object, just call the method of mocked object in sysout(without giving implementation).
Hope it will help someone like me.Peace

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way without mocking and with additional test cases:

```
@Test
public void isEqualTest() {
    StringChecker stringChecker = new StringChecker() {
        @Override
        public String getSecretKey() {
            return "james";
        }
    };

    assertTrue(stringChacker.isEqual("james"));
    assertTrue(stringChacker.isEqual("jam"));
    assertTrue(stringChacker.isEqual("mes"));
    assertFalse(stringChacker.isEqual("oops"));
}
```

BTW, the `isEqual()` can be simplified to one line:

```
public boolean isEqual(String name) {
    return getSecretKey().contains(name);
}
```