# Getting a No Serializer Found for class when trying to test a method with ObjectMapper

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I am getting this exception - `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No serializer found for class org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyCrossClassLoaderSerializationSupport and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.mockito.codegen.Object$MockitoMock$["mockitoInterceptor"]->org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor["serializationSupport"])`

The Testcase I'm writing looks like this

```
@Mock
Object object;

@Mock
ResponseType response;

@Test
public void handleRequest() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    when(mapper.convertValue(object, ResponseType.class)).thenReturn(response)
    new Handler().handleRequest(object);
}
```

The method I'm trying to test:

```
public class Handler{

    public ResponseType handleRequest(Object object) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ResponseType response = mapper.convertValue(object, ResponseType.class);
        return response;
    }
}
```

I see that I can disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, but I have no control over the base class, I can only write a test case. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and what I can add to the test case?
I cannot instantiate an ObjectMapper within the testcase as it has to be a mock, and I tried using  a spy on the ObjectMapper and disable the SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, but neither works. I am also pretty new to Mockito so I'm not sure how I can proceed further. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your test code. You're calling the real ObjectMapper method instead of mocking it (1) and you're not using the created object (even though it's not a mock) in your actual code (2).

---

In the lines below (I've added newlines and a comment, but it's the same as your code) you're creating an instance of `ObjectMapper` (not a mock) and while trying to mock it's behavior, you're actually calling the real method of the created object:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
when(
    // here an actual convertValue method is called on the mapper object
    // which causes the exception you're getting
    mapper.convertValue(object, ResponseType.class)
).thenReturn(response)
```

If you used a method that's not calling the actual method while mocking (useful when working with [spies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052984/what-is-the-difference-between-mocking-and-spying-when-using-mockito)):

```java
doReturn(response)
        .when(mapper)
        .convertValue(object, ResponseType.class);
```

you'd still get an error, but this time it would be:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to when() is not a mock!
Example of correct stubbing:
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someMethod();
```

That's because the `mapper` you're creating is not a Mockito mock/spy, so it cannot be mocked. To fix that you need to use the `mock(...)` method or the `@Mock` annotation ([remember to initialize/open them](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mock_annotation)):

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = mock(ObjectMapper.class);
when(mapper.convertValue(object, ResponseType.class))
        .thenReturn(response);
```

Now neither the initial error (that you were getting) nor `NotAMockException` are thrown, but the mocking has no effect.

---

In your actual code here:

```java
public ResponseType handleRequest(Object object) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ...
}
```

you're creating `ObjectMapper` using `new`. This object is in no way connected to the mock that is created in the test - it is not injected. To fix that, it would be best to store the `ObjectMapper` instance in a field and initialize it with the class creation (injection) - both in the actual code and in the tests:

```java
class Handler {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    Handler(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }
    
    public ResponseType handleRequest(Object object) {
        // use the objectMapper here
    }
}
```

Thanks to that you can pass the mocked `ObjectMapper` in the test to the tested object constructor:

```java
@Test
public void handleRequest() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = mock(ObjectMapper.class);
    when(mapper.convertValue(object, ResponseType.class)).thenReturn(response);

    new Handler(mapper).handleRequest(object);
}
```

Other ways of doing that could be using a factory providing the `ObjectMapper`, also mocked in the tests, or (not recommended) using [mockito-inline with it's mockConstruction method (since Mockito 3.5.0)](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#49).

Comment: I cannot really change the original code, so I don't think this would work for me. However I was able to remove the mocking itself for the unit test and used an actual sample event to bypass this.