# Mocking the methods of hashMap using Mockito

Tags: spring-boot, junit, hashmap, mockito

I am new to java, So I created this class which return if the key is present in map, and if does, it should return the value of the key, but when I testing the code using mockito its not returning the expected.
My method

```
private static Map<String,Long> map1= new HashMap<>();
    public long foo(final String test){
         if(!map1.containsKey(test)){
             return 0L;
         }
         return map1.get(test);
     }
```

And its test method is

```
private static Map<String,Long> map1 = mock(Map.class); 
 @Test
 public void testfoo(){
     when(map1.containsKey("test")).thenReturn(true);
     when(map1.get("test")).thenReturn(2L);
     long value = classUndertest.foo("test");
     Assert.assertEquals(2L, value);
 }
```

But the value I am getting is 0L.

Comment: You're not injecting the mocked object into your tested object, you’re using a separately created one, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73741030/3305737

Comment: Actually I am quite new to java, not understanding the whole of that, would you mind helping me with giving the example of this code.

Comment: 1.Why mocking a `java.util.HashMap`? (Just use a real one (..and put("test", 2L) inside!?:) 2. And if really have to (mock), then ensure the "field" ("map1" of "classundertest") is properly injected.. (for which you need powermock(before mockito 3.4) ..f.m.knowl "how to mock private/static fields")

Comment: @xerx593 if you go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73817517/how-to-mock-hashmap-methods-using-mockito he has the same problem, if you can reply on that or here why it is not working, I think he is using what you tell exactly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to inject Map into the object while testing with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73817517/not-able-to-inject-map-into-the-object-while-testing-with-mockito) (99% identical code)