# How can I detect changes IDbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbset

I am creating a mock IDbSet to allow unit testing of entity framework classes, amongst other things.

However I am really having trouble detecting changes, or even figuring out how to do it at all. Here are my classes so far...

```
public interface IReportContext
{
    IDbSet<Report> Reports {get;}
    public int SaveChanges();
}

public class MockReportContext : IReportContext
{
    IDbSet<Report> Reports {get;}

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        //Need to detect changes here???
    }

    public MockReportContext()
    {
       Reports = new MockDbSet<Report>();
    }
}

public class MockDbSet<T> : IDbSet<T>
{
    readonly ObservableCollection<T> _data;
    readonly IQueryable _query;

    public FakeDbSet()
    {
        _data = new ObservableCollection<T>();
        _query = _data.AsQueryable();
    }

    public FakeDbSet(ObservableCollection<T> data)
    {
        _data = data;
        _query = _data.AsQueryable();
    }

    public virtual T Find(params object[] keyValues)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public T Add(T item)
    {
        _data.Add(item);
        return item;
    }

    public T Remove(T item)
    {
        _data.Remove(item);
        return item;
    }

    public T Attach(T item)
    {
        _data.Add(item);
        return item;
    }

    public T Detach(T item)
    {
        _data.Remove(item);
        return item;
    }

    public T Create()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }

    public TDerivedEntity Create<TDerivedEntity>() where TDerivedEntity : class, T
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<TDerivedEntity>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<T> Local
    {
        get { return _data; }
    }

    Type IQueryable.ElementType
    {
        get { return _query.ElementType; }
    }

    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression IQueryable.Expression
    {
        get { return _query.Expression; }
    }

    IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider
    {
        get { return _query.Provider; }
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _data.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _data.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

This works fine for adding, deleting and retrieving entities. However when I try the following:

```
IReportContext context = new MockReportContext();
context.Reports.Add(new Report()); //Works
Report report = context.Reports.First(); //Works
report.Message = "Hello World!";
context.SaveChanges(); //Does nothing
```

How is it the MockReportContext could know that the report object it returned has changed?? I know using entity framework does this so it must be possible, but I haven't got a clue how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're mostly there, but I'd suggesting using a mocking framework like [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4) (my personal preference) or [Rhino Mocks](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/oss/rhino-mocks) to mock the `IReportContext` for your unit tests, instead of going to the trouble of creating a [Fake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346372/whats-the-difference-between-faking-mocking-and-stubbing) class like `MockReportContext`.  (Alright, learning a mocking framework does involve some trouble, but it'll save a lot of Fake class drudgery down the road.)

I would presume that you're unit testing the code that depends on the `IReportContext`, so you don't need to do anything inside `SaveChanges()`, you just need to assert that your code did call `SaveChanges()` internally if it was supposed to.

[Here's a good overview](http://buildstarted.com/2010/08/24/dependency-injection-with-ninject-moq-and-unit-testing/) of using Moq with Entity Framework's derived DbContext / DbSet classes.

In the above linked overview, if the unit test at the end was testing a method that internally calls `SaveChanges()`, it could additionally verify that `SaveChanges()` was indeed called by your method with the line:

```
dc.Verify(db => db.SaveChanges());
```

You could also do this with your `MockReportContext` class by setting a side property to True inside the `SaveChanges()` class and checking it at the end of your unit test, but a mocking framework is much more flexible and will save the need to write additional classes for unit tests.

If you'd like to avoid using a mocking framework, then here's [how to do it with fakes](http://romiller.com/2012/02/14/testing-with-a-fake-dbcontext/).