# Behavior of doReturn-when and when-thenReturn with mocked vs spied object

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

When using a **spied** object as test subject, If we don't want to call nested methods inside the method we are testing, Which of these (doReturn-when or when-thenReturn) can be used to mock those nested methods?
**Is there a way to avoid getting invoked the real methods inside the method we are going to test?**

Comment: What is unclear in the documentation? https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.18.3/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the reply. Is this means that when we use "doReturn-when" with a spied object, the real methods inside the method we test will never get invoked right? Because i didn't see any where tells that those methods will never get invoked when using "doReturn-when".

Comment: Well, it's the whole point of using doReturn-when: replace the method implementation by a fake one returning what you tell it to return, and spying on the invocations.

Comment: Ok. Previously I thought that both of those methods behave similarly  and they are just syntactically different. Now its bit clear what those does. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact doesn't matter if you use doReturn-when or when-thenReturn method for this specific case, because considering a `@Spy` you will always call the real method.

You can avoid entering other methods by mocking them, but if you are using just Mockito it will be a problem (it doesn't have this approach, but PowerMock does). Particularly I disagree with this approach, because we are being too intrusive in our tests and private flow is a part of the whole flow, but you can do something like this:

```
SomeService mock = spy(SomeService.class);

doReturn(1).when(mock, "getNumber", ArgumentMatchers.anyInt());
```

For more details, you can verify [PowerMock's official documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock). Also, is nice to know [some basic unit testing concepts (stubs, mocks and so on)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346372/whats-the-difference-between-faking-mocking-and-stubbing?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).