# GMock death case - mock function not being called

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

1. I have created a mock of an external socket api in `my_inet.cpp` file.
2. GMock functions for that socket api is in `mock.h` file.
3. I am using my created socket api of `my_inet` in `server.cpp` file.
4. The test is written in `gtest.cpp`.

The death case that is written here is executing as per the output. Output says that the the process died. But it also says that the `socket()` call was never made so the case is shown as failed.

Please tell what is the reason for this and what is the solution.

gtest.cpp

```
TEST(MyTest, SocketConnectionFail)
{
    MockMyTCPAPI obj_myTCP;

    EXPECT_CALL( obj_myTCP, socket( 1, 0, 0 ))
    .Times( 1 )
    .WillOnce( Return( -1 ));

    Server obj_server( &obj_myTCP );

    EXPECT_DEATH( obj_server.InitializeSocket(), "No socket connection!");
}
```

server.cpp

```
int Server::InitializeSocket()
{
  if( ret_val_socket == -1 )
  {
        ret_val_socket = myTCPAPI->socket( PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );

        if( ret_val_socket == -1 )
        {
            printf( "\nNo socket connection!" );
            exit(1);
        }
        return ret_val_socket;
  }
  else
  {
        printf( "Warning! Attempting to create socket again. %d" , ret_val_socket);
        return 2;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

my_inet.cpp

```
int MyTCPAPI::socket( int arg1, int arg2, int arg3 )
{
        return -1;
}
```

Output:

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from MyTest
[ RUN      ] MyTest.SocketConnectionFail

[WARNING] /usr/src/gtest/src/gtest-death-test.cc:825:: Death tests use fork(), which is unsafe particularly in a threaded context. For this test, Google Test couldn't detect the number of threads.

No socket connection!
/home/../Documents/office/tdd/tcp/server/gtest.cpp:49: ERROR: this mock object (used in test MyTest.SocketConnectionFail) should be deleted but never is. Its address is @0x7fff2e94a890.
ERROR: 1 leaked mock object found at program exit.
/home/../Documents/office/tdd/tcp/server/gtest.cpp:56: Failure
Death test: obj_server.InitializeSocket()
    Result: died but not with expected error.
  Expected: No socket connection!
Actual msg:
[  DEATH   ] 
/home/../Documents/office/tdd/tcp/server/gtest.cpp:49: Failure
Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(obj_myTCP, socket( 1, 0, 0 ))...
         Expected: to be called once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
[  FAILED  ] MyTest.SocketConnectionFail (3 ms)
[----------] 1 test from MyTest (3 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (3 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] MyTest.SocketConnectionFail

 1 FAILED TEST
```

Comment: I think you need to print to `stderr`:  `fprintf(stderr, "\nNo socket connection!");`

Comment: Why a close vote? @MikevanDyke thanks. What would happen with that print? Why is that important?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#how-it-works) `EXPECT_DEATH` and `ASSERT_DEATH` spawn a child process which executes the death test statement (`obj_server.InitializeSocket()`). After termination of the child process they check its exit code and if the `stderr` message matches the provided error message (`"No socket connection!"`). Hence, the test only passes if both checks are valid. `stdout` on the other hand is not checked.

Comment: @mike van thanks much. I will try it. Please put it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#how-it-works), `EXPECT_DEATH` and `ASSERT_DEATH` spawn a child process which executes the death test statement (in this case `obj_server.InitializeSocket()`).

After termination of the child process, they check the exit code and the `stderr` message. If the exit code is `0` or the message in `stderr` does not match the expected value, the test is invalid. `stdout` on the other hand is not checked.

Therefore, `printf( "\nNo socket connection!" )` has to be replaced with `fprintf(stderr, "\nNo socket connection!" )` right before the applicatons exits:

```
int Server::InitializeSocket()
{
  if( ret_val_socket == -1 )
  {
        ret_val_socket = myTCPAPI->socket( PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );

        if( ret_val_socket == -1 )
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "\nNo socket connection!" ); // print to stderr here
            exit(1);
        }
        return ret_val_socket;
  }
  else
  {
        printf( "Warning! Attempting to create socket again. %d" , ret_val_socket);
        return 2;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

---

As pointed out in the comments, `EXPECT_CALL` will fail. Using `AnyNumber` when specifying the number of times it might be called could help in this case (only the first call will then return `-1` and the test case might still fail).

TEST(MyTest, SocketConnectionFail)
{
MockMyTCPAPI obj_myTCP;

```
EXPECT_CALL( obj_myTCP, socket( 1, 0, 0 ))
.Times(testing::AnyNumber())
.WillOnce( Return( -1 ));

Server obj_server( &obj_myTCP );

EXPECT_DEATH( obj_server.InitializeSocket(), "No socket connection!");
```

}

Comment: Even with this change, the test should not pass. Don't you still get this error: `Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(obj_myTCP, socket( 1, 0, 0 ))...
         Expected: to be called once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
`?

Comment: @Ari You're right, the `EXPECT_CALL` will still fail, because the parent process will not be able to observe what happens in the child process created by `EXPECT_DEATH`. Therefore, the parent process will not see that `socket(1,0,0)` is called. Using `.Times(testing::AnyNumber())` will help in this case, even though it doesn't test the exact same case.