# How can I test NetworkClient.Connect function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, connection

I am using NetworkClient class to connect to the server. I need to do unit test for this part of the code. How can I write unit test for this function?

```
void Connect(NetworkClient ConnectDev ,String ConnDevIP, int ConnPort)
{
    ConnectDev.Connect(ConnDevIP, ConnPort);
}
```

I have tried something like this;

```
[TestMethod]
void ConnectTest()
{
    NetworkClient ConnectDev = new NetworkClient(); 
    String ConnDevIP = "myserverip";
    int ConnPort = 25000;       
    //Assert.AreEqual();
}
```

Comment: well what exactly is it you want to test? That the IP is correct? That the port is correct? That a connection can actually be made?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Fake or stub object. You can use the link for more detailed information

[What's the difference between faking, mocking, and stubbing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346372/whats-the-difference-between-faking-mocking-and-stubbing)