# Mocking an extended class with Dart Mockito?

Tags: flutter, dart, inheritance, mockito, integration-testing

Is it possible to mock or fake a class that needs to be extended with some other class with `mockito` plugin in Dart?

I have the following example of inheritance:

```dart
abstract class Animal {
  Animal(this.emoji);

  final String emoji;

  String greet();
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  Dog(super.emoji);

  @override
  String greet() {
    return '$emoji: Woof!';
  }
}

class Poodle extends Dog {
  Poodle(super.emoji);
}

class FakePoodle extends Fake implements Poodle {
  // Raises a runtime error:
  // Runtime error: No associated positional super constructor parameter.
  FakePoodle(super.emoji);
}
```

I want to mock the class `FakePoodle` that would still inherit all the properties of the class `Dog`, using a constructor and make it mock with `mockito` at the same time.

Here are my tests:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

void main() {
  group('Dog tests', () {
    test('should return a dog greet', () {
      expect(Dog('').greet(), ': Woof!');
    });

    test('Poodle should return a poodle greet', () {
      expect(Poodle('').greet(), ': Woof!');
    });

    test('Fake Poodle should greet only once', () {
      final FakePoodle fakePoodle = FakePoodle('‍');
      fakePoodle.greet();
      verify(fakePoodle.greet());
    });
  });
}
```

<s>I found the following FAQ section from `mockito` plugin:~</s>

[**How do I mock an extension method?**](https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-do-i-mock-an-extension-method)

> <s>If there is no way to override some kind of function, then mockito cannot mock it. See the above answer for further explanation, and alternatives.</s>

Is there a way I can write integration tests like this in a clean manner?

Comment: There is no extension method in your example.

Comment: [Extension methods](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods) are completely unrelated to what you're asking about, which is extending a class.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, what I meant was "Extending a class".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, [a fake is different from a mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346372/).  Mocks are used to verify behavior. (Specifically, they're used to verify the behavior of how *other* objects interact with the mocked object.  The mocked object is *not* the one being tested.) You cannot use `verify` on a `Fake`.

If you want `FakePoodle` to be a `Fake` but to reuse some of its implementation from `Poodle`, then you can do:

```dart
class FakePoodle extends Fake implements Poodle {
  Poodle _realPoodle;

  FakePoodle(String emoji) : _realPoodle(emoji);

  @override
  String greet() => _realPoodle.greet();
}
```

but it's unclear why you'd want to do that instead of just using an actual `Poodle` instance (unless there are other methods on `Poodle` that you want to have throw `UnimplementedError`s if invoked).

You probably want a *mock* instead because you want to use `verify`.  However, [mocks shouldn't have implementations](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito#best-practices); again, they're used to verify the behavior of some other object being tested, so the implementation of the mocked object usually shouldn't matter.  Wanting to have a mock inherit some of its implementation from a base class conflicts with that philosophy.

But if you still want a mock but still want to reuse implementation (maybe that implementation is particularly complicated and determining a precomputed stubbed response is non-trivial, or maybe the implementation has important side-effects), then you could make a `Mock` wrapper with stubs that call into a real object:

```dart
    test('Fake Poodle should greet only once', () {
      var poodle = Poodle('‍');
      var mockPoodle = MockPoodle();
      when(mockPoodle.greet()).thenAnswer((_) => poodle.greet());
      mockPoodle.greet();
      verify(mockPoodle.greet());
    });
```

Finally, I'll point out that you don't have to use `Mock` or `Fake` if they don't fit what you want.  That is, you also could manually do:

```dart
class TrackedPoodle extends Poodle {
  int greetCallCount = 0;

  TrackedPoodle(super.emoji);

  @override
  String greet() {
    greetCallCount += 1;
    return super.greet();
  }
}
```

---

As an aside, your other terminology is all over the place. "[Extension methods](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods)" are completely unrelated.  Additionally, "[integration tests](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing)" are holistic tests; they usually shouldn't be using mocks or fakes.  Mocks and fakes typically are used to test parts of a program in *isolation*.

Comment: How should I define `MockPoddle` from your second code snippet?

Comment: @matox The same way you'd generate any mock class with Mockito: with `@GenerateNiceMocks` (or `@GenerateMocks`) and performing the code generation step.