# What is the difference between stubs, mocks, and spies as described by Meszaros?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

***Note.** I read a number of SO posts on the matter, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346372/whats-the-difference-between-faking-mocking-and-stubbing/61209739#61209739)*

Here's the [classification](https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) Martin Fowler uses:

> **Dummy** objects are passed around but never actually used. Usually they are just used to fill parameter lists.
>
> **Fake** objects actually have working implementations, but usually take
> some shortcut which makes them not suitable for production (an in
> memory database is a good example).
>
> **Stubs** provide canned answers to
> calls made during the test, usually not responding at all to anything
> outside what's programmed in for the test.
>
> **Spies** are stubs that also
> record some information based on how they were called. One form of
> this might be an email service that records how many messages it was
> sent.
>
> **Mocks** are what we are talking about here: objects pre-programmed
> with expectations which form a specification of the calls they are
> expected to receive.
>
> Of these kinds of doubles, *only mocks insist upon behavior verification*.

So dummies are used in conjunction with *state verification*, mocks are used with *behavior verification*. But then where do spies go here? I know how the term is used by Mockito (a real object with partially mocked behavior), but what is a mock in the "standard" test double classification as described by Fowler (who took it from the ["xUnit Test Patterns" book](https://martinfowler.com/books/meszaros.html) by Gerard Meszaros)?

Also, how do the three relate to each other? Is, for example, one a special case of another? Fowler said spy *is a* stub (spy is a special case of stub), whereas [this article](https://tanzu.vmware.com/developer/guides/test-doubles/) says a mock *is a combination* of stub and spy (mock = stub + spy)

I made a number of attempts at resolving all of this in my head, but so far haven't managed that

Java examples with Junit + Mockito (+ AssertJ, if you want) would be great